# Random Golf of the Day #1: Shuffle an Array

Tags: code-golf, random, array, permutations

## About the Series

I will be running a little series of code-golf challenges revolving around the theme of randomness. This will basically be a [9-Hole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16707/8478) [Golf Course](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19163/8478), but spread out over several questions. You may participate in any challenge individually as if it was a normal question.

However, I will maintain a leaderboard across all challenges. The series will run over 9 challenges (for now), one posted every few days. Every user who participates in *all 9 challenges* is eligible for winning the entire series. Their overall score is the sum of their shortest submissions on each challenge (so if you answer a challenge twice, only the better answer one is counted towards the score). If anyone holds the top spot on this overall leaderboard for **28 days** I will award them a bounty of **500 rep**.

Although I have a bunch of ideas lined up for the series, the future challenges are not set in stone yet. If you have any suggestions, please let me know [on the relevant sandbox post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4750/8478).

## Hole 1: Shuffle an Array

The first task is pretty simple: given a non-empty array of integers, shuffle it randomly. There are a few rules though:

- **Every possible permutation must be returned with the same probability** (so the shuffle should have a uniform distribution). You can check if your algorithm is uniform/unbiased by implementing it in JavaScript on [**Will it Shuffle**](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html), which will produce a matrix of the biases - the result should look as uniform as their built-ins *Fisher-Yates* or *sort (random order)*.
- You must not use any built-in or 3rd-party method to shuffle the array or generate a random permutation (or enumerate all permutations). In particular, **the only built-in random function you may use is getting a single random number at a time**. You *may* assume that any built-in random number method runs in O(1) and is perfectly uniform over the requested interval (in a mathematical sense - you may ignore details of floating-point representation here). If your language lets you obtain a list of *m* random numbers at once, you may use this facility, provided the *m* numbers are independent of each other, and you count it as O(m).
- Your implementation must not exceed a **time complexity of O(N)**, where **N** is the size of the array to be shuffled. For instance, you cannot "sort by random numbers".
- You may either shuffle the array in place, or create a new array (in which case the old array may be modified however you like).

You may write a full program or a function and take input via STDIN, command-line argument, function argument or prompt and produce output via return value or by printing to STDOUT (or closest alternative). If you write a function that shuffles the array in place, you don't need to return it of course (provided your language lets you access the modified array after the function returns).

Input and output may be in any convenient list or string format, but must support arbitrary integers in the range **-2<sup>31</sup> ≤ x < 2<sup>31</sup>**. In principle, your code should work for arrays up to length **2<sup>31</sup>**, although this doesn't necessarily have to fit in your memory or complete within a reasonable amount of time. (I just don't want to see arbitrary size limits to hardcode loops or something.)

This is code golf, so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

## Leaderboard

The following snippet will generate a leaderboard across all challenges of the series.

To make sure that your answers show up, please start every answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

*(The language is not currently shown, but the snippet does require and parse it, and I may add a by-language leaderboard in the future.)*

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_IDs = [45302, 45447, 46991, 49394, 51222, 66319, 89621, 120472]; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!.FjwQBrX2KXuFkv6p2lChi_RjzM19";

/* App */

var answers = [], page = 1, currentQ = -1;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_IDs.join(";") + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}


function getAnswers() {
  $.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      if (data.has_more) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

var SIZE_REG = /\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;((?!&gt;).)*&lt;\/s&gt;|((?!&gt;).)+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;
var NUMBER_REG = /\d+/;
var LANGUAGE_REG = /^#*\s*([^\n,]+)(?=,)/;//

function shouldHaveHeading(a) {
  var pass = false;
  var lines = a.body_markdown.split("\n");
  try {
    pass |= /^#/.test(a.body_markdown);
    pass |= ["-", "="]
              .indexOf(lines[1][0]) > -1;
    pass &= LANGUAGE_REG.test(a.body_markdown);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function shouldHaveScore(a) {
  var pass = false;
  try {
    pass |= SIZE_REG.test(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0]);
  } catch (ex) {}
  if (!pass) console.log(a);
  return pass;
}

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function getAuthorId(a) {
  return a.owner.user_id;
}

function process() {
  answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveScore)
                   .filter(shouldHaveHeading);
  answers.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = +(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0],
        bB = +(b.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0];
    return aB - bB
  });

  var users = {};
  answers.forEach(function (a) {
    var headline = a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];
    var question = QUESTION_IDs.indexOf(a.question_id);
    var size = parseInt((headline.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]);
    var language = headline.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];
    var user = getAuthorName(a);
    var userId = getAuthorId(a);
    if (!users[userId]) users[userId] = {name: user, nAnswer: 0, answers: []};
    if (!users[userId].answers[question]) {
      users[userId].answers[question] = {size: Infinity};
      users[userId].nAnswer++;
    }
    if (users[userId].answers[question].size > size) {
      users[userId].answers[question] = {size: size, link: a.share_link}
    }
  });
  
  
  var sortedUsers = [];
  for (var userId in users)
    if (users.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
      var user = users[userId];
      user.score = 0;
      user.completedAll = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < QUESTION_IDs.length; ++i) {
        if (user.answers[i])
          user.score += user.answers[i].size;
        else
          user.completedAll = false;
      }
      sortedUsers.push(user);
    }  
  
  sortedUsers.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.nAnswer > b.nAnswer) return -1;
    if (b.nAnswer > a.nAnswer) return 1;
    return a.score - b.score;
  });
  
  var place = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedUsers.length; ++i) {
    var user = sortedUsers[i];
    var row = '<tr><td>'+ place++ +'.</td><td>'+user.name+'</td>';
    for (var j = 0; j < QUESTION_IDs.length; ++j) {
      var answer = user.answers[j];
      if (answer)
        row += '<td><a href="'+answer.link+'">'+answer.size+'</a></td>';
      else
        row += '<td class="missing"></td>';
    }
    row += '<td></td>';
    if (user.completedAll)
      row += '<td class="total">'+user.score+'</td>';
    else
      row += '<td class="total missing">'+user.score+'</td>';
    row += '</tr>';
    $("#users").append(row);
  }
}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#leaderboard {
  width: 500px; 
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td.total {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

td.missing {
  background: #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="leaderboard">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <p>
    Missing scores are shown as grey cells. A grey total indicates that the user has not participated in all challenges and is not eligible for the overall victory yet.
  </p>
  <table class="_user-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>User</td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45302/8478">#1</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45447/8478">#2</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46991/8478">#3</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49394/8478">#4</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51222/8478">#5</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66319/8478">#6</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89621/8478">#7</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120472/8478">#8</a></td>
        <td></td><td>Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="users">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am disappointed that we are not allowed to be "clever" and use [library functions other than "get a random number"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45302/random-golf-of-the-day-1-shuffle-an-array#comment107043_45302). Do we want to look at yet another 69 implementations of Fisher-Yates shuffling? Please consider removing this rule in future tasks. Also, why a limit on time complexity? Please consider relaxing it to at least O(n^2); I also think someone might find an especially golfed implementation if you allow O(n!).

Comment: @anatolyg Removing the restrictions amounts to every answer being either `sortby(random)` (the reason for the time restriction) or simply `.shuffle()` (the reason for the built-ins restriction), which I think is a lot less clever than having to implement Fisher-Yates or some other approach.

Comment: If shuffling in place, does a function have to *return* the array, or is it enough that it is modified? Can I write a function for `shuffle(array)` instead of `newArray=shuffle(array)`?

Comment: Nitpicking: your claim that you cannot sort by random numbers, plus the restriction of fixed size integers are incompatible. You **can** sort in linear time if the size of the elements is fixed, what you cannot do is sorting *by comparisons only*.

Comment: @Bakuriu Claiming that you can sort in linear time if the numbers are fixed is a bit like claiming you can do anything in O(1) if the input sizes are fixed. Also the relevant restriction is fixed-size arrays, not fixed-size integers - because the array size determines how large you need your random numbers to be. Anyway, the limitation on time complexity are of course for the general algorithm you implement, whereas the limits on input sizes are in place so you don't have to use arbitrary-precision integers if your language doesn't use them out of the box.

Comment: @Geobits The former is fine. I admit, the spec is currently a bit contradictory in that - will fix.

Comment: For FUZxxl's J solution and aditsu's CJam solution (and maybe others?), while the algorithms used could have linear runtime, the implementations have quadratic runtime. Due to the languages used, for each digit shuffled, memory operations that take linear time with respect to the size of the input are performed. So unfortunately, I believe that these solutions (and probably any in those languages) do not meet the current requirements.

Comment: Can the function take its argument as a global?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos No, that would essentially just be a snippet and not a function.

Comment: Why is Adám's solution coming up as 43319 bytes when it's actually 14?

Comment: @boboquack Because of how stupidly answers are scanned for scores. I edited the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 21):

## Dyalog APL, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

First for the 25-character solution:
[`i{⊃a[⍺⍵]←a[⍵⍺]}¨?i←⌽⍳⍴a←⎕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=A%u21901%202%203%204%205%206%207%20%u22C4%20i%7B%u2283a%5B%u237A%u2375%5D%u2190a%5B%u2375%u237A%5D%7D%A8%3Fi%u2190%u233D%u2373%u2374a%u2190A&run)

```
                      a←⎕ ⍝ evaluated input, assign to "a"
                     ⍴a   ⍝ length
                    ⍳⍴a   ⍝ 1 2 .. length
                   ⌽⍳⍴a   ⍝ length .. 2 1
                 i←       ⍝ assign to "i"
                ?i        ⍝ random choices: (1..length)(1..length-1)..(1 2)(1)
i{            }¨?i        ⍝ for each index ⍺ and corresponding random choice ⍵
   a[⍺⍵]←a[⍵⍺]            ⍝ swap a[⍺] and a[⍵]
        ←                 ⍝ in Dyalog, assignment returns its right-hand side
  ⊃                       ⍝ first element, i.e. a[⍵]
                          ⍝ the result from {} is an array of all those a[⍵]
```

After some equivalence transformations on the above:

```
i {}¨ ?i  ←→  i {}¨∘? i   ⍝ because A f∘g B ←→ A f g B
          ←→  {}¨∘?⍨ i    ⍝ because f⍨ B ←→ B f B
```

we can get rid of the assignment `i←` and save a character:

[`{⊃a[⍺⍵]←a[⍵⍺]}¨∘?⍨⌽⍳⍴a←⎕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=A%u21901%202%203%204%205%206%207%20%u22C4%20%7B%u2283a%5B%u237A%u2375%5D%u2190a%5B%u2375%u237A%5D%7D%A8%u2218%3F%u2368%u233D%u2373%u2374a%u2190A&run)

Comment: ... mind. blown.

Comment: a language I have to read right to left?? wow!

Comment: @Luminous as is often the case with mathematical notation: sin cos ln sqrt x

Comment: @ngn when you put it that way that makes my previous comment look laughable. ha.

Comment: I object. According to [https://mothereff.in/byte-counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%7B%E2%8A%83a%5B%E2%8D%BA%E2%8D%B5%5D%E2%86%90a%5B%E2%8D%B5%E2%8D%BA%5D%7D%C2%A8%E2%88%98%3F%E2%8D%A8%E2%8C%BD%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%B4a%E2%86%90%E2%8E%95), this solution is **51 bytes**! Therefore, I suggest that some of the other solutions are shorter.

Comment: @ronalchn There are 8-bit encodings for APL, like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(codepage)) one or [this](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf) other one; I [heard](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43277/25315) Dyalog uses one of these, as an alternative to Unicode.

Comment: @ngn it's often the case in many languages. `f(g(h(x)))`

Comment: @Luminous You read APL left to right but it's evaluated right to left.

Answer (score 12):

## 80386 machine code, <strike>44</strike> 24 bytes

Hexdump of the code:

```
60 8b fa 0f c7 f0 33 d2 f7 f1 49 8b 04 8f 87 04
97 89 04 8f 75 ed 61 c3
```

Thanks to FUZxxl, who suggested using the `rdrand` instruction.

Here is the source code (can be compiled by Visual Studio):

```
__declspec(naked) void __fastcall shuffle(unsigned size, int array[])
{
    // fastcall convention:
    // ecx = size
    // edx = array
    _asm
    {
        pushad;             // save registers
        mov edi, edx;       // edi now points to the array

    myloop:
        rdrand eax;         // get a random number
        xor edx, edx;
        div ecx;            // edx = random index in the array

        dec ecx;            // count down
        mov eax, [edi + 4 * ecx];   // swap elements
        xchg eax, [edi + 4 * edx];  // swap elements
        mov [edi + 4 * ecx], eax;   // swap elements
        jnz myloop;

        popad;              // restore registers
        ret;
    }
}
```

Yet another Fisher-Yates implementation. Most of the golfing was achieved by passing parameters in registers.

Comment: You could have also used `rdrand` for shits and giggles.

Comment: @FUZxxl I totally forgot about it! Too bad it removes the most interesting part about my answer...

Answer (score 9):

## Java, 88 <s>101</s>

A basic Fisher-Yates shuffle does the trick. I get the feeling it'll be used pretty commonly here, since it's quick and easy to implement. There's some loop/assignment cramming here, but there's honestly not *too* much to golf; it's just short by nature.

```java
void t(int[]s){for(int i=s.length,t,x;i>0;t=s[x*=Math.random()],s[x]=s[i],s[i]=t)x=i--;}
```

With some line breaks:

```java
void t(int[]s){
    for(int i=s.length,t,x;
        i>0;
        t=s[x*=Math.random()],
        s[x]=s[i],
        s[i]=t
    )
        x=i--;
}
```

This shuffles in place, modifying the original array `s[]`. Test program:

```java
public class Shuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        new Shuffle().t(a);
        for(int b:a)
            System.out.print(b+" ");
    }
    void t(int[]s){for(int i=s.length,t,x;i>0;t=s[x*=Math.random()],s[x]=s[i],s[i]=t)x=i--;}
}
```

Comment: No, the challenge states that you can assume that it "*is perfectly uniform over the requested range*". The requested range of `Math.random()` has a size which is a power of two, so this doesn't meet spec.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure I agree. The docs say the range is [0.0 - 1.0]. Whether that can be represented perfectly by a FP number doesn't matter if I can assume it's perfectly uniform over that range.

Comment: @PeterTaylor "approximately" only means "up to the issues inherent to PRNGs in general". The range here is `[0.0..1.0]`, otherwise this would have been accessing out of the bounds.

Comment: @PeterTaylor unless you read the rule as "you may assume the PRNG generates floats with probability perfectly proportional to their density, but you may not assume that floats are an accurate representation of the real line", which would be unfair to languages that use floating point randomness as their source of perfectly random indexes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Jan's and Geobits' interpretations are indeed how I intended the rule - that you *don't* have to worry about the actual cycle-length of your PRNG.

Comment: @MartinBüttner the cycle length is not the issue here - that is covered by your rule. The coarseness of floats is.

Comment: @JanDvorak, actually it doesn't generate floats with probability proportional to their density, or you'd be much more likely to get a number less than 0.5 than a number greater than 0.5. But it's selecting (approximately) uniformly from a finite set of doubles, not an uncountable set of reals.

Comment: @PeterTaylor by "proportional to their density" I meant inverse proportionality. As in, 0.6 has its ULP twice as big as 0.3, so it should be twice as likely to occur.

Comment: Getting this distribution out of a perfect bit source might be an interesting challenge, actually.

Comment: Wow... Almost as short as a python solution.

Comment: @TheBestOne It's one byte *shorter* than the only currently-posted python solution ;)

Comment: Not any more! :D

Comment: @Sp3000 Your turn ;)

Comment: Annoyingly, a C# clone of this requires 5 more characters. (You need a `new Random()` and it's cheaper to assign `Next(i)` to `x` and shuffle the increments around than to call `NextDouble()`.)

Comment: Can't you replace `s[i]=t)x=i--;` with `s[x=--i]=t);` to reduce 1 byte?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Not really. `x=i--` needs to be executed first in the loop or else it's undefined for the first iteration.

Comment: But you have `int i=s.length` right inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, I mean `x` is undefined. You can try it if you want, but simply moving it breaks the program.

Comment: For some reason I find that extremely weird. I have no way to test it now (maybe ideone, but I'm not very familiar with Java). Nor knowledge. But I still find it weird since you have `s[x*=Math.random()]` and that runs fine.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `x=i--` is run before `x*=Math.random()` due to the loop structure. If I move it, then it comes after and `x` is undefined the first time it tries to multiply.

Comment: Now I get it. Still find it weird, but I get it. Thanks a lot for the explanation. Dang, I had my hopes high!

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 86 bytes

```py
from random import*
def S(L):i=len(L);exec"i-=1;j=randint(0,i);L[i],L[j]=L[j],L[i];"*i
```

This is a function which shuffles the array in place without returning it, using a straightforward implementation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Getting random numbers from Python is *expensive*...

Thanks to @xnor and @colevk for tips.

Comment: That range expression looks pretty cumbersome. Surely it's shorter to count down manually as `while i:i-=1;...`?

Comment: @xnor Yeah it is - thanks for that. I keep forgetting that `while` tends to be shorter than `for` for this sort of thing...

Comment: Awww... now my Java answer isn't beating this. I was quite happy for a very short while :(

Comment: You can save another 2 bytes by making `i=len(L)` and putting the decrement at the beginning of the while loop.

Answer (score 8):

### J, <s>45</s> 44 characters

This was a tricky one.

```
<@({.,?@#@}.({,<^:3@[{])}.)&>/@(<"0@i.@#,<)
```

Here is an explanation:

1. `# y`: The *tally* of `y`, that is, the number of elements in `y`.
2. `?@# y`: A random number uniformly distributed over the range from `1` to `(#y)-1`.
3. `x { y`: The item *from* `y` at index `x`.
4. `(<<<x) { y`: All items except the item at index `x` in `y`.
5. `x , y`: `y` *appended* to `x`.
6. `x ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) y`: The item at index `x` in `y`, then all the other items.
7. `(?@# ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) ]) y` A random it from `y`, then all the other items.
8. `x {. y`: The first `x` items *taken* from `y`.
9. `x }. y`: The first `x` items *dropped* from `y`.
10. `x ({. , }.) y`: The first `x` items *taken* from `y`, then the first `x` items *dropped* from `y`
11. `x ({. , (?@# ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) ])@}.) y`: The first `x` items *taken* from `y`, then the first `x` items from `y` processed as in number 7.
12. `x ({. , ?@#@}. ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) }.) y`: The same thing with the *drop* pulled in to save one character.
13. `u/ y`: `u` *inserted*  between the items of `y`.
14. `< y`: `y` *boxed*.
15. `<"0 y`: Each item of `y` *boxed*.
16. `i. y`: *integers* from `0` to `y - 1`.
17. `i.@# y`: *integers* from `0` to `(#y) - 1`.
18. `(<"0@i.@# , <) y`: Integers from `0` to `(#y) - 1` each *boxed* and then `y` in a single box. This is needed because arrays in J are uniform. A box hides the shape of its content.
19. `x u&v y`: like `(v x) u (v y)`.
20. `> y`: `y` *opened*, that is, without its box.
21. `x ({. , ?@#@}. ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) }.)&> y` the phrase from number 12 applied to its unboxed arguments.
22. `({. , ?@#@}. ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) }.)&>/ y` the phrase from number 21 *inserted*  between items of `y`.
23. `({. , ?@#@}. ({ , <^:3@[ { ]) }.)&>/@(<"0@i.@# , <) y` the phrase from number 22 applied to the the result of the phrase from number 18, or, a uniform permutation of the items of `y`.

Comment: I just can't distinguish all the parentheses. And that triple boxing `<@<@<@[` is also a mystery... Waiting for explanation. :)

Comment: Once this gets explained, I might be much more likely to upvote this answer ;-)

Comment: @randomra Here you go.

Comment: @JanDvorak Is the explanation satisfying?

Comment: Great explanation! I didn't know about all the boxed use of `from` (`{`). And I really like the `&>/` trick to manipulate a list. I'm sure I could have used it a couple times before.

Comment: Is this really O(n)? If the lists are arrays and not linked lists some of these operations take O(n^2) total time (O(n) used n times) like step 4 and 10. (I could easily be wrong just asking.)

Comment: @randomra That's my fear, too. J has optimized code for many common things though, so it might be O(n), it might also be O(n²). I'm not really sure.

Comment: @FUZxxl I believe the fear is correct. I made a comment to the main post stating that your solution and aditsu's CJam solution both unfortunately get knocked down to O(n²) due to list operations that actually take O(n), which I confirmed with timed tests. Waiting for OP to comment on the matter.

Comment: @Runer112 You did actually time this? In that case, I'm afraid this is indeed invalid.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I timed it. I expressed this concern earlier as a comment to the original post, which also mentions aditsu's CJam solution as having a similar problem (which I also timed).

Comment: @Runer112 Yes, I left a comment regarding this on aditsu's answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

[Test it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com)

Yet another Fisher-Yates implementation. Is essentially the same as @Sp3000 python solution, just in pyth.

```
FNrlQ1KONJ@QN XXQN@QKKJ)Q
```

Thanks to @Jakube for the swapping trick

```
<implicit>    Q=input()
FNrlQ1        For N in len(Q) to 1, only goes len Q-1 because how range implemented in pyth
 KON          K = random int 0-N
 J@QN         J=Q[N]
 <space>      Suppress print
 XXQN@QKKJ    Swap K and J
)             End for
Q             Print Q
```

Comment: You can save two bytes by combining those two list assignments: ` XXQN@QKKJ` instead of ` XQN@QK XQKJ`.

Comment: @Jakube thanks for the tip. I knew there must have been a way to swap values in a list, and this is really smart. You should add it to the tips list.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>68</s> <s>56</s> 44

Like many other solutions, this uses the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Using [nutki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45302/random-golf-of-the-day-1-shuffle-an-array/45374?noredirect=1#comment107493_45374)'s comment, 12 characters are saved by using `$_` instead of `$i` and performing the operations in the array indices.

44:

```
sub f{@_[$_,$j]=@_[$j=rand$_,--$_]for 1..@_}
```

56:

```
sub f{$i=@_;$j=int(rand$i),@_[$i,$j]=@_[$j,$i]while$i--}
```

This is my first codegolf.

Comment: Not a bad start, I did not know that you can use `@_[...]` as rvalue like that. Can be golfed further into `sub f{@_[$_,$j]=@_[$j=rand$_,--$_]for 1..@_}`.

Answer (score 3):

### Octave, <s>88</s> 77 bytes

```
function s=r(s)for(i=length(s):-1:1)t=s(x=randi(i));s(x)=s(i);s(i)=t;end;end
```

Yet another Fisher-Yates implementation... Should be fairly straightforward if I add the usual line returns and spacing:

```
function s=r(s)
  for(i=length(s):-1:1) # Counting down from i to 1
    t=s(x=randi(i));    # randi is builtin number generator for an int from 0 to i
    s(x)=s(i);
    s(i)=t;
  end
end
```

<s>The "end" keywords really kill the golf score here, unfortunately.</s> Hey, I can use "end" instead of "endfor" and "endfunction"!

Comment: Just FYI, the "bytes" isn't really required by the code, it just makes sure there *is* a headline, which contains a comma (to separate the language) and at least one number after the comma, and then just chooses the last number that isn't crossed out. Having "bytes" in there is still nice though. ;)

Comment: You could save 1 byte by using `numel` instead of `lenght`. As a bonus your program would also work with 2-D arrays aka matrices ;)

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
i,t;s(a,m)int*a;{for(;m;a[m]=t)t=a[i=rand()%m--],a[i]=a[m];}
```

Just a straight implementation of Fischer-Yates that sorts the given array in place. Compiles and links perfectly fine with the visual studio compiler (vs2013, haven't tested the other versions) and the Intel Compiler. Nice looking function signature is `s(int array[], int length)`. I'm legitimately impressed I beat Python and Ruby.

This does assume `srand()` is called and rand() is implemented properly, but I believe this rule allows for that:

```
You may assume that any built-in random number method runs in O(1) and is perfectly uniform over the requested interval
```

Nicely formatted version:

```
index, temp;
shuffle(array, length) int* array;  {
    for(;length; array[index] = temp)
        index = rand() % length--,
        temp = array[length],
        array[length] = array[index];
}
```

Comment: I think it suffices to make the function header `s(a,m)*a{`, but I'm not sure and don't want to test either. You might want to do a `xor`-swap, like in `a[i]^=a[m]^=a[i]^=a[m]`. This also avoids the need to declare `t`.

Comment: @FUZxxl I believe an xor swap causes problems if `i==m`.

Comment: @Geobits indeed. I missed that possibility.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why that wasn't working... should have remembered that. Also I do need `s(a,m)int*a` for visual studio and the intel compiler. Don't have gcc or clang installed to test, but I assume they will also complain.

Comment: This is pretty impressively golfed. After trying a lot of modifications that didn't save anything, I did manage to see a way to save 2 characters. If you change the swap order so that the first swap statement becomes `t=a[i]`, you can then move the `i=rand()%m--` statement inside as the array index.

Comment: I copied into VS2013 and turned off warnings...still there are 12 errors. No variable declarations and variables before '{' etc.

Comment: its probably compiling it as c++ code, which is stricter than c. compile it from a VS developer command prompt using `cl`. also be sure the file is .c, not .cpp

Comment: You can remove 1 byte by transforming `for(;m;a,b,c);` into `for(;m;c)a,b;`

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 57 bytes

```rb
->a{a.size.times{|i|j=rand(i+1);a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]};p a}
```

#### Input (as lambda function):

```
f.([1,2,3,4,5])
```

#### Output:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 77

```
(x)->{for(int i=x.length,j,t;;t=x[j*=Math.random()],x[j]=x[i],x[i]=t)j=i--;};
```

It's a lambda taking `int[]` and returning void. My first attempt seemed not very interesting, so I decided to have it exit by throwing an exception.

Test program:

```
interface shuff {
    void shuff(int[] x);
}
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        shuff s = (x)->{for(int i=x.length,j,t;;t=x[j*=Math.random()],x[j]=x[i],x[i]=t)j=i--;};
        int[] x = {3, 9, 2, 93, 32, 39, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 0};
        try {
            s.shuff(x);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException _) {}
        for(int a:x) System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it cheating to use a lambda to get around having to write a function signature, when you have to supply a delegate in order to use the lambda anywhere? Also... can't you drop the parentheses around `Math.random()`?

Comment: @Rawling You could vote in [this meta question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/java-function-literals). Currently, there are 9 votes in favor of lambdas, and 0 against. Yes, the parentheses can be removed.

Comment: Huh, if there's a meta post and a so-far-consensus then fire away. (And enjoy the two-lower golf score on me :p)

Comment: I think, it's unfair for function to stop by exception in a normal case, is it?

Comment: @Qwertiy To each his own... You think it's unfair, I think it's great.

Comment: Does the `x` need to be wrapped in parentheses?

Comment: Instead of `shuff` interface, you can use predefined `java.util.function.Consumer<int[]>` functional interface.

Answer (score 2):

## Golflua, 37

[How to run Golflua?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1216/7162)

```
~@i=1,#X`r=M.r(i)X[i],X[r]=X[r],X[i]$
```

The input is provided as a table in the variable X. The table is shuffled in place.

Example usage:

```
> X={0,-45,8,11,2}
> ~@i=1,#X`r=M.r(i)X[i],X[r]=X[r],X[i]$
> w(T.u(X))
-45 0 8 11 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 79 bytes

```js
f=function(x){n=length(x);for(i in 1:n){j=sample(i:n,1);x[c(i,j)]=x[c(j,i)]};x}
```

This is a straightforward implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle. The R function `sample` draws a simple random sample of a given size from a given vector with equal probability. Here we're drawing a random sample of size 1 at each iteration from the integers `i`, ..., `n`. As stated in the question, this can be assumed to be O(1), so in all this implementation should be O(N).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>82 90 83</s> 93 bytes

Note: This variation the Fisher-Yates shuffle is actually Martin Büttner's solution, with some code paring by alephalpha. `s` is the input array.
Nothing fancy-smancy, but sometimes the simple things are the most elusive.

```
f@s_:=(a=s;m=Length@a;Do[t=a[[r=RandomInteger@{1,m-1}]];a[[r]]=a[[m]]; a[[m]]=t,{n,1,m-1}];a)
```

Comment: You can use `Do` here. It's shorter than `While`.

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 67

Also implementing Fisher-Yates.

```
a=input('');n=numel(a);for i=1:n;k=randi(i);a([i,k])=a([k,i]);end;a
```

I thought it was too bad I could not use Matlab's `randperm` function. But after some fiddling around, I thought I may look at the source of `randperm` to see how it is done, and I was astonished to see that there was just one line: `[~,p] = sort(rand(1,n))` =)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 44

```
sub f{($_[$x],$_)=($_,$_[$x=rand++$i])for@_}
```

Another perl in 44 characters. Example use:

```
@x=(1..9);f(@x);print@x
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 46 bytes

```
For(X,dim(L1),2,-1:randInt(1,X→Y:L1(X→Z:L1(Y→L1(X:Z→L1(Y:L1

1   111   2  1111112       1111112 111112 1112 111112 1112
```

[Source for byte count](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens)

Comment: You're missing the `End`.

Answer (score 2):

## K, 31 chars

```
f:{{l[i:x,1?x]:l@|i}'|!#l::x;l}
```

Not quite as short as the one I put up before (which got disqualified)...oh well.

It's a basic Fisher-Yates shuffle. This was built with lots of help [from the Kona mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kona-user/lf2LC9ivPRw).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66

This function shuffles the array in place. It also returns a byproduct array that is NOT the shuffled output and must not be considered.

```
F=a=>a.map((v,i)=>a[a[i]=a[j=0|i+Math.random()*(a.length-i)],j]=v)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
XH`HnYr&)XHxvHHn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x/hkeCRF1mkphnhUVHm4ZH3/3@0oYKRgrGCiYKpgpmCuYJF7Ne8fN3kxOSMVAA)

Fisher-Yates in MATL. Almost a third of this program is devoted to the letter `H`, which corresponds to the clipboard function in MATL.

Basically, `H` stores the unused items from the input, while the stack keeps track of the shuffled list.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 12

```
rÈiMqZÄ Y}[]
```

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cshpTXFaxCBZfVtd&input=WzExLCAyMiwgMzMsIDQ0LCA1NV0KLVE=)

-10 (about half ;) thanks to @Shaggy!

I have been wanting to try out a golfing language, and the Japt interpreter had good documentation and a way to try things out in the browser.

Below is the strategy I took:

- Reduce input seeding with an empty array
- At each step, find a random slot to insert the current element

Comment: Welcome to Japt, good to have you with us. I think [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cshpTaxZfVtd&input=WzExLCAyMiwgMzMsIDQ0LCA1NV0KLVE=) works for 9 bytes, using the same method. If the RNG isn't satisfactory, though, then try [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cshpTXFYysQgWX1bXQ==&input=WzExLCAyMiwgMzMsIDQ0LCA1NV0KLVE=) instead.

Comment: @Shaggy - Thanks for the tips! :) I ended up using a slightly modified version of your 2nd solution. Since the 3rd parameter of the reduce function is an index, we already know the length.

Answer (score 1):

## STATA, 161

```
di _r(s)
set ob wordcount($s)
token $s
g a=0
foreach x in $s{
gl j=floor(runiform()*_n)+1
replace a=`$j' if word($s,_n)=`x'
replace a=`x' if word($s,_n)=`$j'
}
l
```

Expects input as space separated numbers. I can remove the headers and observation numbers from the output if you would like, but otherwise this is shorter.

Comment: What's `_n` in this?

Comment: _n is the number of the current observation.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam - 30

```
q~_,,W%{_I=I)mr:J2$=@I@tJ@t}fI
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Example input: `[10 20 30 40 50]`
Example output: `3020401050` (add a `p` at the end of the code for pretty printing)

<s>If the code is allowed to take the input from the stack (like a function), then the first 2 characters can be removed, reducing the size to 28.</s>

**Explanation:**

The code is longer than I hoped, due to the lack of a "swap" operator for arrays
(to be implemented later :p)

```
q~            read and evaluate the input (let's call the array "A")
_,,           make an array [0 1 2 ... N-1] where N is the size of A
W%            reverse the array, obtaining [N-1 ... 2 1 0]
{…}fI         for I in this array
    _I=       push A[I]
    I)mr:J    push a random number from 0 to I (inclusive) and store it in J
              stack: A, A[I], J
    2$=       get A[J]
    @I@t      set A[I] = A[J]
              stack: former A[I], A
    J@t       set A[J] = former A[I]
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, I'm afraid this is invalid. At the very least `_` is O(N) (inside an O(N) loop). Unfortunately, I don't see a way to work around that in CJam.

Comment: Lists are handled like immutable objects, so duplication is just implemented as duplicating the reference. It's actually the `t` that kills it, as it can't mutate the list and now must create a copy.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was about to post the same thing as Runer112; yes there might be a problem with `t`, I'd like to improve it in future versions..

Comment: So this code follows the spirit of the question, but not the "letter", due to internal language implementation issues.

Answer (score 1):

### SQF, 91 bytes

```
params["i"];{n=floor random count i;i set[_forEachIndex,i select n];i set[n,_x]}forEach i;i
```

Comment: This is biased (see "swap (i <-> random)" on Will It Shuffle), but you can turn it into Fisher-Yates (which is unbiased) by replacing `%x` with `%i`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 27 bytes

[Test it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

```
FkQJOhlYaY?@YtJJkIJ XYtJk;Y
```

This is an implementation of the incremental Fisher-Yates shuffle, mentioned second [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript ES6, 69

```
a=>{m=a.length;while(m)[a[m],a[i]]=[a[i=~~(Math.random()*m--)],a[m]]}
```

It's Fisher–Yates.

PS: Can be tested in Firefox

Comment: @MartinBüttner, removed it :)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 170

```
import System.Random
import Data.Array.IO
s a=do(_,n)<-getBounds a;sequence$map(\i->do j<-randomRIO(i,n);p<-a%i;q<-a%j;writeArray a j p;return q)[1..n]where(%)=readArray
```

Another Fisher-Yates solution inspired by the algorithm at https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle.

`s` is a function which has signature: `IOArray Int a -> IO [a]`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES 6), 61

```js
S=a=>(a.map((c,i)=>(a[i]=a[j=Math.random()*++i|0],a[j]=c)),a)
```

You can test it [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html) by just adding a line that says `shuffle = S` (Firefox only).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 93 bytes

```
a->{for(int b=0,c,d=0,e=a.length;b<e;c=a[b],a[b]=a[d],a[d]=c,b++,d=b)d+=Math.random()*(e-b);}
```

Example usage: http://ideone.com/RqSMnZ

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 41 bytes

```perl
sub f{push@b,splice@_,rand@_,1while@_;@b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrbqgtDjDIUmnuCAnMznVIV6nKDEvBUgZlmdk5gD51g5Jtf@LEysV0jRs7DT/G3IZcRlzmXCZcv3LLyjJzM8r/q/ra6pnYGgAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), 46 bytes

*Invalid, since language postdates question. Is otherwise a perfectly valid answer.* [Try it *ici*!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=didubEtXwqtuKXYnSEMqbXJobnR2J1MuS24kS1tuXT1LW0hdO0tbSF09UyR9Sw)

```
v'nlKW«n)v'HC*mrhntv'S.Kn$K[n]=K[H];K[H]=S$}K
```

### Explanation

```
v'nlKW«n)v'HC*mrhntv'S.Kn$K[n]=K[H];K[H]=S$}K
                                              implicit: K = input array
v'n                                           set n to
   lK                                           the length of K
     W«n)                                     while(--n){
         v'H                                    set H to
            C     t                               the integer part of
             *mr                                  Math.random() times
                hn                                  n+1
                   v'S                          set S to
                      .Kn                         the nth member of K
                         $K[n]=K[H];K[H]=S$     eval as javascript (perform swap)
                                           }  }
                                            K K
                                              implicit: print K
```

This runs in O(n) time, I believe, as `n` is strictly decreasing.

<sub><sub>I used [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm-in-javascript-modern-and-inside-out-versions) as the basis for the code</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
!a=for i=length(a):-1:1;j=rand(1:i);a[[i,j]]=a[[j,i]]end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxCoQwEIXhPqcYOwMKm0KLyJxEUgya1QnDKCHC3j4bu1f830uPMM21doTfKwOjRD3K2ZP1o/NuSZhJ9955tgutKw8pBGwjDRxC1L2@6ges0OqPAcLtEolbacRN1kBHBu7MWkTbqXnJHw)

Fisher-Yates.

`a[[i,j]]=a[[j,i]]` is slightly shorter than `a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]`.

`rand(1:i)` samples from the range `1:i`.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 56 bytes

Fisher-Yates algorithm of course.

```
DEF S A
FOR I=1-LEN(A)TO-1SWAP A[-I],A[RND(1-I)]NEXT
END
```

Downwards FOR loops are expensive (`STEP -1`), so instead you can just negate the start/end values, which only adds 1 extra character. This is the code if FOR implicitly went backwards when the end value is lower than the start:

```
DEF S A
FOR I=LEN(A)-1TO 1SWAP A[I],A[RND(I+1)]NEXT '1 character less
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, <strike>39</strike> 27 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
$args-split','|sort{random}
```

Accepts input as commandline arguments, and outputs as an array.

Comment: Welcome! You can use `random` only. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/778/80745

Answer (score -1):

**VBA/Basic, 96**

Someday I will find a good challenge for vba or basic, but not today

Fisher-Yates

```
Sub s(o(), n)
For i = 0 To n
r = Int(Rnd() * (n + 1))
x = o(r)
o(r) = o(i)
o(i) = x
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is biased. It's what Will it Shuffle calls "swap (i <-> random)". You can turn it into actual Fisher-Yates by replacing `n + 1` with `i + ` though.

Comment: ty, but damm then I need to add 'step -1'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.