# Randomised list, formatted nicely

Tags: code-golf, number, random

## Challenge

#### Task

Given a number `N`, output 2 NxN squares; each line of each square is a random permutation of [0, N); the squares are separated by a newline

#### Rules

- Produce a randomised list of length `N`, separated by space
- Repeat this N*2 times
- Separate each output with a newline, with 2 newlines at the midpoint
- The value of `n` must be "obvious", you can get it via stdin; argument; whatever, but there must be a distinct value somewhere, so the value of `n` can't just be scattered across your program.

#### Example

Given `n = 4`, the output could be:

```
1 2 0 3
2 3 1 0
2 0 3 1
2 0 3 1

0 3 2 1
3 1 0 2
0 1 3 2
0 2 1 3
```

Lowest number of bytes wins

Comment: Do columns need to be aligned? - it matters for n>9

Comment: nah, i wouldn't worry

Comment: Is it not a code-golf question (I mean code-golf tagged) ?

Comment: Does the function need to be able to output all random permutation?

Comment: I should think so, otherwise you could just hardcode it to output "1 2 3 4" and call it random ( http://xkcd.com/221/ )

Answer (score 9):

## J, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Thanks to @randomra for shaving off two characters:

```
?~2&,]
```

Previously I had:

```
?~($~2&,)
```

These are functions, you can apply them to an argument directly or store them in a variable and then use them:

```
   (?~2&,$]) 5
1 0 4 2 3
2 4 0 3 1
2 3 1 0 4
2 3 0 1 4
3 0 1 4 2

1 4 0 2 3
2 1 4 3 0
2 3 1 0 4
2 3 1 4 0
0 1 2 3 4

   f=.?~2&,$]
   f 5
4 2 3 0 1
3 4 1 0 2
3 4 0 2 1
1 2 4 3 0
2 0 4 1 3

2 1 3 0 4
1 3 4 2 0
2 4 1 3 0
3 2 1 0 4
3 0 4 2 1
```

Comment: `?~2&,$]` saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 13

```
V2VQjdoOQUQ)k
```

Pretty simple program, I believe it follows the spec.

[Try it online here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V2VQjdoOQUQ)k&input=5)

Explanation:

```
                   : Q = eval(input)
V2                 : Do the next part twice
  VQ       )       : Do the stuff before the ) Q times
    jd             : Join the resulting list on spaces
      oOQUQ        : order range(Q) by random_int( from 0 to Q )
            k      : print nothing (pyth auto-pads each print with a newline)
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 54

I feel there should be a better way, but at the moment

```
n=5;for(i in 1:(n*2))cat(sample(n)-1,rep('\n',1+!i-n))
```

Edit: Replace rank(runif(1:n))-1 with sample(1:n)-1. Used rep instead of if. Thanks to Alex A for a few more.

Test run

```
> n=5;for(i in 1:(n*2))cat(sample(n)-1,rep('\n',1+!i-n))
0 3 1 2 4 
0 1 4 2 3 
2 3 4 0 1 
4 1 0 2 3 
1 0 3 4 2 

4 3 1 0 2 
3 0 1 2 4 
4 2 3 1 0 
4 2 1 0 3 
3 1 0 2 4
```

Comment: You can save a byte by doing `n=scan();for(i in 1:(2*n))` rather than assigning `n` inside `for()`.

Comment: You can save another 2 bytes by doing `sample(n)` rather than `sample(1:n)` since they're equivalent.

Comment: And what is `1+!i-n` doing?

Comment: @AlexA. It was the shortest way I could think of doing 1 except when i == n, so it is equivalent to `1+(i==n)` .  I also got rid of the vector constructor in the cat

Comment: Ah, okay. Clever. Right now you're hard-coding `n` but doesn't it still need to come from input? Or does simply defining it like that constitute "obvious" per the OP's rules? (It _is_ obvious...)

Comment: @AlexA.  I wondered about that, but I noticed a number of others were doing it, including the OP

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 22 bytes

```
l~{_{_,mrS*N@}*N\}2*;;
```

Input via STDIN. I feel like there must be a much way to do this.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~%7B_%7B_%2CmrS*N%40%7D*N%5C%7D2*%3B%3B&input=4)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash+coreutils, 61

Input as a command-line arg.

```
seq -f"((%g))&&echo \`seq 0 $[$1-1]|shuf\`||echo" -$1 $1|bash
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <strike>20</strike> 19 bytes

```
ri_a*0+2*{,mrS*}%N*
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_a*0%2B2*%7B%2CmrS*%7D%25N*&input=4) ([for Firefox](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_a*0%2B2*%7B%2CmrS*%7D%2525N*&input=4)).

Other solutions:

```
{T,mrS*N}_ri:T*N](T*
"T,mrS*N"ri:T*:F~NF~
LN]"T,mrS*N"ri:T*f{~}
```

Comment: Is a trailing newline ok? You can put N in the block

Comment: @aditsu Then there will be two trailing newlines.

Comment: Oh, right.. it's not obvious in the online interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>190</s> 187 bytes

```java
void f(int n){int k=0,i,t,x,o[]=new int[n];for(;k<n;o[k]=k++);for(k=0;k++<n*2;)for(i=n;i>0;t=o[x*=Math.random()],o[x]=o[i],o[i]=t,System.out.print(o[i]+(i>0?" ":k==n?"\n\n":"\n")))x=i--;}
```

Clunky, but it does the job (that's Java's motto, right?). Pretty simplistic: it fills an array, then repeatedly uses my earlier [Fisher-Yates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45305/14215) to shuffle and print. I tried using `Collections.shuffle()` instead, but it was a touch longer once you add in the import.

Ah well, such is life.

With line breaks:

```java
void f(int n){
    int k=0,i,t,x,o[]=new int[n];
    for(;k<n;o[k]=k++);
    for(k=0;k++<n*2;)
        for(i=n;
            i>0;
            t=o[x*=Math.random()],
            o[x]=o[i],
            o[i]=t,
            System.out.print(o[i]+(i>0?" ":k==n?"\n\n":"\n"))
        )
            x=i--;
}
```

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the `+" "`, and using `i>0?" ":k==n?" \n\n":" \n"` instead.

Comment: @Ypnypn Saved three with it, since I don't need trailing spaces with newlines. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

### Clip, 29

```
[zjm[ Jm[ jkwRRzwS}Rz}R2:2N]n
```

Takes input from STDIN.

```
[z                         ]n  .- z is the numeric value of the input -.
  j                     :2N    .- join with two newlines              -.
   m[                }R2       .- do twice                            -.
      J                        .- join with a newline                 -.
       m[         }Rz          .- do z times                          -.
          j     wS             .- join with spaces                    -.
           kw                  .- wrap each number                    -.
             R                 .- shuffle                             -.
              Rz               .- list of the first z numbers         -.
```

Example run:

```
> java -jar clip4.jar random.clip
4
2 1 0 3
3 1 2 0
1 0 2 3
3 1 0 2

3 0 1 2
0 1 2 3
3 2 0 1
0 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 90 bytes

```py
from random import*
def f(n):S="*L,=range(n);shuffle(L);print(*L);"*n;exec(S+"print();"+S)
```

I'm sure there's a better method for handling the newline break in between, but I'm having trouble coming up with a way.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <strike>139</strike> 138 bytes

```
import random as r
n=4
s=range
t=s(0,4)
print('\n\n'.join('\n'.join(' '.join('%d'%i for i in r.sample(t,n)) for j in t) for k in s(0,2)))
```

EDIT: Knocked off a byte

Answer (score 1):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;public class A{public static void main(String[]a){int n=Integer.decode(a[0]);for(int x=0;x<2;x++){for(int i=0;i<n;i++){java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,n).parallel().forEach(k->out.print(k+" "));out.println();}out.println();}}}
```

As short as I could manage in Java - 265 bytes.

It takes an ordered stream of n integers and concurrently prints them separated by a space, so the output order is non-deterministic and it does this per line.

EDIT:

If done as only a function:

```
void g(int n){for(int x=0,i=0;x<2;x++){for(;i<n;i++){java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().forEach(k->out.print(k+" "));System.out.println();}System.out.println();}}}}}
```

This is 179 bytes; the ordering may not seem very random - but as far as I'm aware it is quite non-deterministic.

Comment: You could use a function instead.

Comment: This has got to be the worst RNG ever. I like it for sheer cheek, but the "randomness" is terrible :)

Comment: Plus, you could declare `x` and `i` together with `n` and scrape off a few characters.

Comment: I agree that it's non-deterministic, but our standard definition of "random" can be found here for future reference: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/14215

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 109

```
$n=4;$p=range(0,$n-1);for($k=0;$k<2;$k++){for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){shuffle($p);echo join(' ',$p)."\n";}echo"\n";}
```

New implemented solution uses 1 more bytes. But now fulfill OP requirement.

Old solution which do not randomize permutation of line.

## PHP, 108

```
$n=4;for($k=0;$k<2;$k++){for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)echo rand(0,$n-1)." ";echo"\n";}echo"\n";}
```

Comment: This solution is wrong. "each line of each square is a random permutation of [0, N)"

Comment: Rule 3, quoting: "`the value of n can't just be scattered across your program`". The first 5 characters are `$n=4;`. There is nothing reading anything from STDIN, argument, POST, GET, COOKIE, SESSION.... Nothing.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, Many of other answers also uses the variable assignment instead of parameter/STDIN. And they also get more upvotes. So I am confusing if using assignment will broke rule. I think what OP wants not to use constant 4 or any other integer in program to same these 5 bytes. See `but there must be a distinct value somewhere`

Comment: @abc667, I did not understood how each line is not randomized when individual element is random.

Comment: Lines aren't suppose to be random but be random permutation of [0,n). Line 1 1 1 1 is wrong. There must be every number from (1,2,3,4) and every number must appear exactly once.

Comment: @abc667 Yes you are right, I added new solution using 2 more bytes but do what it is required to. Unfortunately solution is much similar to Ismael's solution.

Comment: Your solution (the one that works) is almost exactly like mine, but yours has 3 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - <s>76</s> 75

```
N: 4 do b:[loop N[print random collect[repeat i N[keep i - 1]]]]print""do b
```

Ungolfed:

```
N: 4 

do b: [
    loop N [
        print random collect [
            repeat i N [keep i - 1]
        ]
    ]
]

print ""
do b
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (106 bytes):

This one was quite unexpectedly hard.

But here is a somewhat large solution:

```php
<?for(;3>$j++;$o='',$z=range(0,($i=$n=$_GET[n])-1)){for(;$i--;shuffle($z))$o.=join(' ',$z)."
";echo"$o
";}
```

This can be rewritten to Javascript quite 'easily'.

For this to work, you must access the file over an http server, with `?n=<number>` appended to the name.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 69

```
r=->(n){[0,0].map{(1..n).map{(0..n-1).to_a.shuffle*" "}*"\n"}*"\n\n"}
```

Sample output:

```
puts r[5]
```

yields:

```
3 0 2 1 4
0 4 1 3 2
2 1 0 4 3
0 4 2 1 3
4 1 2 3 0

4 0 3 2 1
3 1 0 2 4
3 4 0 2 1
0 2 3 4 1
3 2 4 0 1
```

and

```
puts r[7]
```

yields

```
5 4 0 6 1 3 2
6 3 1 2 4 0 5
5 2 1 0 6 4 3
4 0 5 2 3 1 6
0 6 3 1 4 5 2
6 3 0 2 5 1 4
2 4 1 0 6 5 3

0 1 4 3 6 5 2
3 5 4 2 6 1 0
2 3 5 1 4 6 0
3 0 5 2 1 4 6
4 6 5 0 2 3 1
6 5 3 2 0 4 1
3 4 6 1 0 5 2
```

Comment: I think I can shave some bytes by making a helper function, give me a minute.

Comment: It was too complicated to create a helped function :(

Comment: Your lines appear to be random numbers in [0, N-1], whereas they should be random permutations of [0, N-1].

Comment: @Théophile fixed; interestingly it's the same length as before

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, <strike>105</strike> <strike>98</strike> <strike>95</strike> 84 bytes

```scala
(n:Int)=>{def s=0.until(n).permutations take n map(_ mkString " ") mkString "\n";s+"\n\n"+s}
```

#### Ungolfed

```scala
def squares(n: Int): String = {
  def square(n: Int): String = 0.until(n).permutations.take(n).map(_.mkString(" ")).mkString("\n")
  square(n)+"\n\n"+square(n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 201

```
void f(int n)
{
std::vector<int> v;int N=n;
while(n--)v.push_back(n);
for(int i=0;i<2*N+1;i++)
{
random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end());
if(!(i==N))for(int j=0;j<N;j++)printf("%d ",v.at(j));
else puts("");
puts("");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2FFL<.rðý,}¶?
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyM3Nx0av6PCGw3t1ag9ts///3wQA)

Or alternatively:

```
·FIL<.r})»2ä»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HY3Tx8bvaJazUO7jQ4vObT7/38TAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
2F          # Loop 2 times:
  F         #  Inner loop the (implicit) input amount of times:
   L<       #   Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input-1]
     .r     #   Randomly shuffle it
       ðý   #   Join it by spaces
         ,  #   Pop and output it with trailing newline
  }¶?       #  After the inner-loop is done: print a newline

·           # Double the (implicit) input
 F          # Loop that many times:
  IL<       #  Push a list in the range [0, input-1]
     .r     #  Randomly shuffle it
 })         # After the loop: wrap everything on the stack into a list
   »        # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
    2ä      # Split it into a list of two equal-sized strings
      »     # And join those by newlines as well (which is output implicitly as result)
```

If a leading instead of trailing newline is allowed, the first version could be `2F¶?FL<.rðý,` instead, to save a byte on the `}`: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyO3QNns3Hxu9osMbDu/V@f/fBAA).