# Generate ;# code

Tags: code-golf, code-generation

Related to: [Make a ;# interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121921/68910)

In the above linked challenge the task was to create an interpreter for the esoteric language `;#`.

### The `;#` language

The language has exactly two commands: `;` and `#` (all other characters are ignored by the interpreter):

`;`: Increment the accumulator

`#`: Modulo the accumulator by 127, print the corresponding ASCII character and reset the accumulator to 0.

### Challenge

Because I am lazy but still want to test some more testcases, I need a program or function which converts plain text to `;#` code.

### Input

The input is a string, taken either as argument or through stdin. It will only contain printable ASCII characters and newlines.

### Output

The output is the generated `;#` program by returning, or printing to stdout. As long as the program is valid, it may contain excess characters other than `#` and `;` as all other characters are ignored.

### Examples

```
Input: Hello, World!
Output: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#

Input: ABC
Output: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#

Input: ;#
Output: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#
```

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=122139,OVERRIDE_USER=73772;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Glad to see ;# is getting attention!

Comment: You can test your output [here](https://tio.run/##K84o@P/fmnygTIya//8B ";#+ – Try It Online"), as ;#+ is a superset of ;#.

Comment: @Adám I'll be damned, it's already on TIO

Comment: Can the output contain additional character? `;#` ignores all other characters, so the generated program would still work.

Comment: @Dennis Yes it can

Comment: When the input contains a newline, do you need the output to contain 13 `;` and a `#`?

Comment: @Chowlett Well, depends on what newline sequence was used in the input. `\n` should be 10 `;` and `\r` should be 13 `;`.

Comment: Uh, yes. I meant 10. <.<;

Comment: None of the answers implement the modulus you've aksed (and I think you meant % 128).

Comment: @Benoît: The modulus is irrelevant when generating code, since it's always easier to generate code that uses the minimum number of `;`. Secondly, 127 is correct, as stated in the linked question that contains the specification of the ;# language.

Comment: Can you edit the fact that the output may contain additional characters other than `;` and `#` into the question, please? A few people, myself included, may be able to save some bytes with that knowledge.

Comment: @Shaggy: But that is part of the question; you're supposed to output valid ;# code and in ;# code anything except `;` or `#` is simply ignored. Thus you can have other characters in it, as they don't change the validity of the ;# program.

Comment: @Joey, the fact that "all other characters are ignored" is mentioned in the intro doesn't necessarily explicitly permit any other characters in the output.

Comment: This isn't really transpiling. "Generate #; code" is a better title. I'm going to change it to that.

Comment: Can we take input as an array of individual characters?

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry for the (very) late answer. The input should be taken as a string, I will clarify this.

Comment: May we include a trailing `;;;;;;;;;;#` in the output?

Comment: @Shaggy This challenge is so old, it's hard to reinterpret the rules... but I'd say no, because that would generate trailing spaces in the program's output. So unless your input contains a trailing space, the output of your generated program shouldn't either.

Comment: That's OK, I was expecting that answer. It'd be a trailing newline, though, not a trailing space.

Answer (score 54):

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 61 bytes

*[Outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122210/64121) by Conor O'Brien*

```
;;;;;;;(~;;;;;~-;-)~>:~;;;;(~;;;;;;~-;-)~>~-*((;~<#~):<#-:-*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/shp#@28NARp1YKpO11pXs87Oqg5JDCZYp6uloWFdZ6Ncp2llo6xrpaul@f@/R2pOTr5CeH5RTooiAwA)

Note that the input has a trailing null byte.

Comment: Points for style.

Comment: I approve of this answer :D definitely the right language for the job

Answer (score 36):

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 40 bytes

```
;;;;;~+++++++>~;~++++:>*(-(;~<#~):<#-*:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/shp#@28NAnXaEGBXB2Fa2Wlp6GpY19ko12la2Sjrallp/v/vkZqTk68Qnl@Uk6LIAAA) Input is terminated with a null byte.

### Explanation

The code is split into two parts: generation and iteration.

### Generation

```
;;;;;~+++++++>~;~++++:>
```

This puts the constants `;` and `#` into memory as such:

```
;;;;;~+++++++>~;~++++:>
;;;;;                     set A to 5
     ~                    swap A and B
      +++++++             add B to A 7 times
                          (A, B) = (5*7, 5) = (35, 5)
             >            write to cell 0
              ~           swap A and B
               ;          increment A
                ~         swap A and B
                          (A, B) = (35, 6)
                 ++++     add B to A 4 times
                          (A, B) = (59, 6)
                     :    increment cell pointer
                      >   write to cell 1
```

### Iteration

```
*(-(;~<#~):<#-*:)
*                    read a character into A
 (            * )    while input is not a null byte:
  -                  flip Δ
   (     )           while A != 0
    ;                decrement
     ~               swap A and B
      <              read ";" into A
       #             output it
        ~            swap A and B
           :         decrement cell pointer
            <        read "#" into A
             #       output it
              -      flip Δ
               *     take another character from input
                :    increment cell pointer
```

Comment: All this from a joke language I made when I was bored. I'm flattered.

Comment: @RandomUser :D it's a fun concept to play around with

Comment: huh. What if I want the program to print out a null byte in ;#?

Comment: `#` @tuskiomi. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K84o@P9f@f9/AA ";#+ – Try It Online")

Comment: @ConorO'Brien how would I input that into your program?

Comment: @tuskiomi With this program, you can't It is not needed, however, since we are guaranteed that "It will only contain printable ASCII characters and newlines."

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
O”;ẋp”#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@//qGGu9cNd3QVAWvn///8eqTk5@QA)

```
O”;ẋp”#  Main Link
O        Map over `ord` which gets the codepoint of every character
 ”;ẋ     Repeat ';' the required number of times
     ”#  '#'
    p    Cartesian Product; this puts a '#' at the end of each element in the array

Implicit Output shows as a single string
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Emigna
-1 byte thanks to @Dennis

Comment: Could you do `O”;ẋ;€”#` instead?

Comment: @Emigna Ah, yes, thanks. I don't quite get how that works but I kind of understand it. Thanks!

Comment: `;€` can become `p`.

Comment: @Dennis Oh now I understand how that works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 13):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>59</s> <s>54</s> 33 bytes

-21 bytes with [KSab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15858/ksab)'s [bfbrute](https://github.com/ksabry/bfbrute) tool.

```
+[>[+<<]>>>+>++>--<],[[>.<-]<.>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO9ouWtvGJtbOzk7bTlvbTlfXJlYnOtpOz0Y31kbPTif2/3@P1JycfIXw/KKcFEUA)

Answer (score 11):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 6 bytes

```
■•;2•#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/gs2#@/9o2oJHDYusjYCE8v//Hqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpigA)

#### Reversible hexdump (xxd)

```
0000000: ff 07 3b 32 07 23                                ■•;2•#
```

#### How it works

```
■       Map the rest of the program over  all code points C of the input.
 •;         Push ';'.
   2        Multiply; repeat ';' C times.
    •#      Push '#'.
```

Comment: `■` = what the heck?

Comment: `2` is the multiplication command? GS2 is weird :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer executes the code for each of the input's character's code point o_O

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That sounds fancier than it is. `■` is just *map*, and GS2 implements strings as lists of integers.

Comment: @ETHproductions GS2 isn't character-based; it interprets the source code as a raw byte stream, and there's usually no connection between the instruction and the CP-437 character the byte encodes. In x86_64 byte code, `2` is XOR...

Comment: Considering that the program is usually non-printing, wouldn't it be easier to just paste a hexdump? ■ seems to be 0xFE and • seems to be 0x7 (in CP437), but took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: @Joey Added a hexdump. Unfortunately, the interpreter on TIO (only) takes CP-437 encoded source code, for reasons I no longer remember. Hexdumps would have indeed been a better choice.

Comment: @Dennis Ooh so GS2's strings are like GolfScript's (where to get a char at a specific index you do `1/=` and even `\1/=` sometimes) in a sense.

Answer (score 10):

## Taxi, 779 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.[c]Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Charboil Grill.Go to Charboil Grill:n 1 l 3 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 r.[p]; is waiting at Writer's Depot.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to The Underground:n 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan "n" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Zoom Zoom:n 3 l 2 r.Go to Writer's Depot:w.Switch to plan "p".[n]# is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 3 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.Switch to plan "c".[e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#rZJLa8MwEIT/yuAcehP0cUqOLeTYQFoKNT6oytoWVbVCkjH99a5fSY2TulB6kISk3ZnRh5otIzJ2HCIe81wrWte4hmmH71ax0@q9cpBwMgSyBXkUrG3Rdd2X7LCv6FMMKqf92h77cTfqpCrb1zqqsit0RloklEDnsAy2BB1QSx1b5V8spX9jbbD12piT7/SwNze4Hcai2lNJeLYH8oXnyh5GuRevI/mrgAdyHHseXqQu20xCQsZZ3aLRhK84Jz7QuhlJDfezaN9ExRyj/QPGyw9/Zf7op9atw9cm@gHJWQiXiNRmq2VCF7WOVuafAS59xnl61aanrGk2qy8)

Ungolfed:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 1st left 4th right 1st left.
[c]
Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Charboil Grill.
Go to Charboil Grill: north 1st left 3rd left 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Writer's Depot: west 1st right.
[p]
; is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to The Underground: north 1st right 1st left.
Switch to plan "n" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 3rd left 2nd right.
Go to Writer's Depot: west.
Switch to plan "p".
[n]
# is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 3rd left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 1st left 4th right 1st left.
Switch to plan "c".
[e]
```

Explanation:

```
Pick up stdin and split it into characters.
Covert each character to ASCII.
Print ";" as you count down from that ASCII to zero.
Print "#".
Pickup the next character and repeat until done.
```

Comment: +1 I just love languages such as this and Mornington Crescent, the code is just so beautiful!

Answer (score 10):

## Brainfuck, 43 bytes

```
+[+[<]>->++]--[>--<+++++++]>-<,[[<.>-]>.<,]
```

Null byte terminates the program.

### Explanation

```
+[+[<]>->++]          59 (semicolon) location 5
--[>--<+++++++]>-       35 (hash) location 7
<,[                     input location 6
    [   while input byte not 0
        <.>     print semicolon
        -       decrement input byte
    ]
    >.< print hash
,]  loop while input not null
```

Comment: That's impressively small for Brainf*ck.

Comment: almost competes with the python answer. Impressive.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Ç';×'#«J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4Xd368HR15UOrvf7/90jNycnXUQjPL8pJUQQA)

**Explanation**

```
Ç          # convert each input char to its ascii value
 ';×       # repeat ";" those many times
    '#«    # append a "#" to each run of semi-colons
       J   # join to string
```

Comment: -1 without `Ç` by taking input as a list of codepoints.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
[print(";"*ord(s)+"#")for s in input()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@x9dUJSZV6KhZK2klV@UolGsqa2krKSZll@kUKyQmQdEBaUlGpqx//97pObk5OsohOcX5aQoAgA)

Comment: `for s in input():print(";"*ord(s)+"#")` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @ovs that moment when you assume a list comprehension is shorter.

Comment: That doesn't accept a string with a newline does it?

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 bytes

```
i:0(?;\"#"o
o1-:?!\";"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59pZaBhbx2jpKyUz5VvqGtlrxijZK30/39aZnEGAA), or at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

Input is STDIN, output is STDOUT. In ><>, characters and ASCII codes are the same thing, so all we need to do is read a character, print `";"` and decrement the character until it's 0, then print `"#"` and loop until there's no more input left.

Answer (score 5):

## F#, 79 bytes

```fs
let c i=System.String.Join("#",Seq.map(fun c->String.replicate(int c)";")i)+"#"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcuxCsIwEIDh3aeIV4QE27xAsVBdxDWDc4kXOUgvMYmD4LvHDC7i@v98Lg9r4FCrxyKsoIN55YKrNiUR3/UlEEvooDf40OsSpXuysMP03QmjJ7sUlMSNKxhBkdo3UK2AM3ofenENyd@28J5iM8Ux7DJs2p6Pp/84dr@tfgA)

## Expanded

```fs
// string -> string
let convert input =
    System.String.Join(
        "#",      // join the following char seq with "#"
        input     // replicate ";" n times where n = ASCII value of char c
        |> Seq.map (fun c-> String.replicate (int c) ";") 
    ) + "#" // and add the last "#" to the output
```

convert takes the input string and outputs a ;# program

### Usage

```fs
convert "Hello, World!" |> printfn "%s"
convert "ABC" |> printfn "%s"
convert ";#" |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: We need more F# answer

Comment: @aloisdg I'll do my best :)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - 36 bytes

```python
for i in input():print';'*ord(i)+'#'
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITMPiApKSzQ0rQqKMvNK1K3VtfKLUjQyNbXVldX//1f3SM3JyddRCM8vyklRBwA)**

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell, <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
$args|% t*y|%{';'*$_+'#'}
```

Pretty straightforward. Takes input as command-line argument. Output is a valid ;# program that prints the requested text.

Comment: It need to join result strings.

Comment: @mazzy: From the task description: *»As long as the program is valid, it may contain excess characters other than `#` and `;` as all other characters are ignored.«*

Comment: as you wish :-)

Comment: quotation marks can be removed. `$args` is enough.

Comment: Unless the argument is numeric.

Comment: ?! rule: `The input is a string...`. But as you wish ;-)

Comment: Ah, good point.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
s=>1+[...s].map(c=>";".repeat(Buffer(c)[0])+"#")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcHBDoIwDADQX9FyaQM2ejbjwIk/4EB2WEZnNJUuG/r7471P@Icayzsft902acm16sZHvzJz9fwNGaMb4QlcJEs4cPqlJAUjrXdPPXRALdpeTYXVXpgQZlG14bJY0e0KRO0E)

- 1 byte saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

---

### Alternatives

If we can take input as an array of individual characters then 5 bytes can be saved.

```
a=>1+a.map(c=>";".repeat(Buffer(c)[0])+"#")
```

If we can also output as an array then 2 more bytes can be saved.

```
a=>a.map(c=>";".repeat(Buffer(c)[0])+"#")
```

Comment: `\n` should becomes `;;;;;;;;;;#`.

Comment: Hmm ... that's strange. Guess I'll have to roll back to the longer solution, so. Thank, @Neil.

Comment: I think you could change `.` to `[^]`, which would still leave it a byte shorter than `map/join`?

Comment: Yup, that did the job, @Neil :)

Comment: Just a heads up, the `join()` in your previous answer was unnecessary given the specification for `;#`, and you can also declare that the input for your function is an array of characters, though the second suggestion is a bit of a stretch. Either way, that brings you down to at most 48 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a full function declaration like `f=x=>x**x`?

Comment: @Ausername, no, if the function isn't recursive then we do not count the variable assignment (e.g., `f=`) in our byte count.

Comment: @Shaggy Ok, thanks for that! I have some answers to shorten...

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 47 bytes

```
+++++++[->++++++++>+++++<<]>+++<,[[>.<-]>>.<<,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKide2gLG0Iw8YmFsSw0YmOttOz0Y21A5I2OrH//3uk5uTk6yiE5xflpCgCAA)

See also: [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122169/66421), which takes a similar approach, but with a different method of generating constants and a different cell layout.

---

### Explanation:

This challenge lines up with the brainfuck spec pretty well, which means the solution is essentially trivial. Brainfuck takes input as ASCII values, which is exactly what ;# need to output as.

The schematic for transpiling is simple: Generate the ASCII value for `;` and `#`, print `;` equal to the ASCII value of the input character, print `#`, repeat for every input.

```
+++++++[-             7
         >++++++++       * 8 = 56
         >+++++<<        * 5 = 35 (#)
       ]>+++<                  56 + 3 = 59 (;)
,[                    Input into first cell
  [>.<-]              Print ;'s equal to ASCII input
  >>.<<,              Print one #
 ]                    End on EOF
```

Comment: [-2 Bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKide2gLG0bGzBlFwsSsdGJBkrp2cTa6NnpxP7/DwA) Only -1 if you’re avoiding negative cells

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
StringRepeat[";",#]<>"#"&/@ToCharacterCode@#<>""&
```

### Explanation

[image]

Converts the input string to a list of character codes, then `Map`s the function `StringRepeat[";",#]<>"#"&` over the list, then `StringJoin`s the result with the empty string.

Comment: Why do you need the `<>""`?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Without it I would be left with a list of strings for each character. `StringJoin`ing (`<>`) the empty string concatenates each string.

Comment: Forgot about that :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>23</s> <s>17</s> 10 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

```
"#@~k:*k,;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X0nZoS7bSitbx/r/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks a lot. I was able to golf two bytes more off. This now on par with Pyth, Husk and CJam!

Answer (score 3):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 19 bytes

Since there's an [interpreter in Aceto](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121990/21173), I thought there outta be an Aceto answer to this challenge as well. It fits neatly in a 2rd order Hilbert curve:

```
\n;*
'o'p
`!#'
,dpO
```

First of all, we read a single character (`,`) and duplicate and negate it to test whether it is a newline (`d!`, when reading a newline, an empty character is normally pushed on the stack). I then use what I think is a pretty clever trick to handle the newline case compactly:

`` `'\n ``

If the value on the stack is `True` (we read a newline), that code means: *do* (`` ` ``) put a character literal on the stack (`'`), which is a newline: `\n`.

If the value on the stack is `False` (we didn't read a newline), that code means: *don't* (`` ` ``) read a character literal (`'`). That means the next character is executed as a command. Fortunately, a backslash escapes the next command (it makes it so that it doesn't get executed), so `n` doesn't print a newline (which is what `n` usually does).

The rest of the code is straightforward; we convert the character on the stack to the integer of its unicode codepoint (`o`), we push a literal semicolon (`';`), multiply the number with the string (`*`, like in Python), `p`rint the result, push a literal (`'`) `#`, `p`rint it too, and go back to the `O`rigin.

Run with `-F` if you want to see immediate results (because buffering), but it works without, too.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 24 bytes

```
s/./";"x(ord$&)."#"/ges
```

Run with `perl -pe`.

Alternative solution:

```
say";"x ord,"#"for/./gs
```

Run with `perl -nE`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fourier](http://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier), 19 bytes

```
$(I(`;`&j)`#`0~j&i)
```

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=JChJKGA7YCZqKWAjYDB-aiZpKQ)

To run, you must enclose the input string in quotation marks.

***Explanation pseudocode***

```
While i != Input length
    temp = pop first char of Input
    While j != Char code of temp
        Print ";"
        Increment j
    End While
    Print "#"
    j = 0
    Increment i
End While
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Solace](https://github.com/splcurran/Solace), 11 bytes

Yay, new languages.

```
';@jx{'#}Ep
```

#### Explanation

```
';           Push the code point of ';' (59).
  @j         Push the entire input as a list of code points.
    x        For each code point in the input, repeat 59 that many times.
     {  }E   For each resulting list of 59s:
      '#      Push the code point of '#' (35).
          p  Flatten and print as unicode characters.
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```r
for(x in utf8ToInt(scan(,'')))cat(rep(';',x),'#',sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SKNCITNPobQkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0ddXVNTMzmxRKMotUBD3Vpdp0JTR11ZXac4tcBWSUnzv7XyfwA)

Comment: After 3 years, I've finally managed to find a [shorter approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211712/95126)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 11 bytes

```
O⌠';*'#o⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@@//qGeBurWWunL@o56FvucW//@v5JGak5OvoxCeX5SToqgEAA)

Explanation:

```
O⌠';*'#o⌡MΣ
O            convert string to list of ASCII ordinals
 ⌠';*'#o⌡M   for each ordinal:
  ';*          repeat ";" that many times
     '#o       append "#"
          Σ  concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
'#',¨⍨';'⍴¨⍨⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@RR2wR1ZXWdQyse9a5Qt1Z/1LsFzHzUNzXUORgor6DukZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqM6lrs4FFHR0coYxrZXVAQ)

`⎕UCS` Convert to Unicode code points

`';'⍴¨⍨` use each code point to reshape (*⍴* = *Rho* ≈ *R*; *R*eshape) a semicolon

`#',¨⍨` append a hash to each string

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>28</s> 25 bytes

24 bytes, plus the `-n` command line switch to repeatedly operate on `stdin`.

```
$_.bytes{|b|$><<?;*b+?#}
```

3 bytes saved (and output corrected on newlines!) thanks to manatwork.

Comment: You could avoid the use of `.ord` by working directly with character codes: `$_.bytes{|b|$><<?;*b+?#}`. There is difference: this one also encodes the newline in the input. Not sure what the question owner intends to say by “It will only contain printable ASCII characters and newlines.”, but to me sounds like newlines should be encoded too.

Comment: Your Ruby-fu exceeds mine, @manatwork - I'd forgotten about `bytes`. I've asked OP about newlines up top and will edit this afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 54 Bytes

```php
for(;$o=ord($argn[$i++]);)echo str_repeat(";",$o)."#";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUsv6fll@kYa2Sb5tflKIBVhKtkqmtHatprZmanJGvUFxSFF@UWpCaWKKhZK2ko5KvqaekDNT2HwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 12 bytes

```
'#I.h%&';d&O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@u7KmXoaqmbp2i5v//v0dqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiIA)

#### Explanation

```
'#    Push 35, the code point of '#'.
I     Read a code point C from STDIN. Pushes -1 at EOF.
.h%   Compute C%(C+1). For C == -1, this terminates the program due to division
      by zero. For C > -1, this just gives back C, so it does nothing.
&';   Pop C and push that many 59s (the code point of ';').
d     Push the stack depth, which is C+1.
&O    Print that many code points from the top of the stack.
      The IP wraps around to the beginning and another iteration of this
      loop processes the next character.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 48 bytes

```
for(;$c?:~$c=~ord($argn[$i++]);)echo";#"[!++$c];
```

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 30 characters

(26 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
explode|map(";"*.+"#")|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr 'explode|map(";"*.+"#")|add' <<< 'Hello, World!' | jq -Rrj '[scan(".*?#")|gsub("[^;]";"")|length%127]|implode'
Hello, World!
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/s/azUJuDB8td)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
sm_+\#*\;C
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm_%2B%5C%23%2a%5C%3BC&input=%22ABC%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 24 bytes

```
{chars|[";"*ord(_),"#"]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyf9r86OSOxqLgmWslaSSu/KEUjXlNHSVkptvZ/bmJmnkI1lwIQpGloctX@90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUQQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Minecraft Functions (18w11a, 1.13 snapshots), 861 bytes

Uses four functions

a

```
scoreboard objectives add a dummy
scoreboard objectives add b dummy
scoreboard objectives add c dummy
scoreboard objectives add d dummy
scoreboard objectives add e dummy
scoreboard players set x a 0
scoreboard players set x b 0
scoreboard players set x c 1000
scoreboard players set x d 0
scoreboard players set x e 1
function b
function c
```

b

```
scoreboard players operation x b = x i
scoreboard players operation x b %= x c
scoreboard players operation x a *= x c
scoreboard players operation x a += x b
scoreboard players operation x i /= x c
execute if score x i > x d run function b
```

c

```
scoreboard players operation x i = x a
scoreboard players operation x i %= x c
function d
tellraw @s "#"
scoreboard players operation x a /= x c
execute if score x a > x d run function c
```

d

```
tellraw @s ";"
scoreboard players operation x i -= x e
execute if score x i > x d run function d
```

"Takes input" from a scoreboard objective named `i`, create it with `/scoreboard objectives add i dummy` and then set it using `/scoreboard players set x i 5`.  Then call the function using `/function a`

Limitations:

Minecraft does not really support strings, or input, or much of anything really, so due to language limitations, input is passed to the `i` scoreboard, as ascii values, so "ABC" would be `65066067`.

However, due to *another* limitation, scoreboard objectives can only store numbers with 10 or less digits, so all strings must be passed in chunks of three letters.  For example, "Hello, World!" must be converted to `'072101108', '108111044', '032087111', '114108100', '033'` and the function must be called for each of these numbers.  Hope that counts as a valid input method.

This python function will convert the strings, it does not change the string in any way, other than getting the ascii representation,

```
def convert(string):
    line = ''.join('{:0>3}'.format(ord(c)) for c in string)
    print([line[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(line), 9)])
```

Minecraft may not have been the best choice of language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
ạ{;";"j₍,"#"}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhdXWStZKWY@aenWUlJVqH26dkPz/v5JHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqi0v8oAA)

```
ạ                   % Convert the string into its ascii codes
 {          }ᵐ      % map this over each resulting code:
  ;";"j₍            %   repeat ";" that many times
        ,"#"        %   tack on a "#" at the end of that
              c     % at the end of the map, concatenate the results of the map
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 94 bytes

```
{{({}[()])<>((((((()()()){})){}{}())()){}{})<>}{}<>(((((()()()){}())){}){}{})<>}<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v7pao7o2WkMzVtPGTgMCNEFQs7oWhKtrgUwNCAuoAkjClMFUAQmQWpgCGzuQgTZ2EPb//9bK/3WTAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
cat(strrep(';',utf8ToInt(scan(,''))),'',sep='#')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4pKgotUBD3Vpdp7QkzSIk3zMPKJicmKeho66uqakJJHWKUwts1ZXVNf87Ojn/BwA)

Outputs 'pure' ;# code with no other characters.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
paste(strrep(';',utf8ToInt(scan(,''))),'#')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyCxuCRVo7ikqCi1QEPdWl2ntCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR11dU1NTR11ZXfO/o5PzfwA)

Outputs 'dirty' ;# code with various other characters ([,],0-9, ,") that are all ignored.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>216</s> <s>201</s> <s>191</s> 175 bytes

This started out a lot shorter until I remembered that we had to handle line breaks in the input - each line in Rockstar is a separate input - and *then* discovered, in what I can only assume to be a bug, that the space character passes equality tests with the empty string `\t`, `\n` & `0`.

```
listen to S
O's""
while S
X's0
while S at X
Y's31
C's-1
until C is S at X
build Y up
cast Y into C

let O be+";"*Y+"#"
build X up

listen to S
if S
let O be+";"*10+"#"


say O
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

This 151 byte version includes a newline after each `#`, which, although being valid in ;# as they're simply ignored, would fail when passed back to [my Rockstar interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211736/58974).

```
listen to S
while S
X's0
while S at X
Y's31
C's-1
until C is S at X
build Y up
cast Y into C

say ";"*Y+"#"
build X up

listen to S
if S
say ";"*10+"#"
```

Answer (score 2):

## A0A0, <strike>103 057</strike> 102 945 bytes

https://gist.github.com/stefvanschie/a32e23f45553fc19b79b9cb7159c7e04

(I think putting that many characters into a codebox here is a bit too much.)

Yes, I'm serious. A0A0 has loops, but this solution would require nested loops (a loop for reading a character and within that a loop for printing the right amount of semicolons). I'm not even certain if nested loops are possible at all. I have a solution that can display the correct code for a single character, since that doesn't require any nested loops in only 143 bytes. If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. The code for a single character is also on the gist.

The reason this is still possible is by using a dirty work-around: write code for every single character, then jump to that spot for the right character. Since there are only a finite amount of printable ASCII characters and you can't go above character 126 because of the modulo 127, this is possible. This is where the byte count comes from. I generated almost 600 lines of code that does exactly that.

The important part is at the top

```
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1A0
A0I1D8M5V0G0A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

Most of this serves as an infinite loop, but the code in between `A0` on the third line is actual important code.

```
I1D8M5V0G0
I1         ; reads a character and stores it on the next operand as its ascii value
  D8       ; subtracts 8 from the operand
    M5     ; multiply the operand by 5
      V0   ; the operand, value is put on the next instruction
        G0 ; set by the operand, jumps this amount of lines down
```

On every correct line you can find a loop with the right amount of prints for each semicolon `P59` and hash tag `P35`, as well as another jump to jump back to this input loop.

Rev: Improved positioning of the character prints

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
q{i';*'#}%
```

Explanation:

```
q           e# Read input
 {          e# For each character in the input:
  i         e#  Get code point
   ';*      e#  Repeat ';' that many times
      '#    e#  Add a '#'
        }%  e# End for
e# Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
c@'#i';pX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y0AnI2knO3BY&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

---

### Explanation

```
     :Implicit input of string U
c@   :Map over the codepoints of characters in the string
'#   :"#"
i    :Prepend
';   :";"
p    :repeated
X    :The current codepoint times
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 36 Bytes

```
-join([char[]]"$args"|%{';'*$_;'#'})
```

just prints `;`s and then a `#`

Comment: You can compact it: `-join($args|% t*y|%{';'*$_+'#'})` 32 bytes ))

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Mathematica, 69 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[Flatten[{Table[59,{,#}],38}&/@ToCharacterCode[x]]]
```

`Table[59,{,#}]` is a short replacement for `ConstantArray[]`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
c;f(){for(;~(c=getchar());puts("#"))while(c--)puts(";");}
```

Hope you don't mind a newline after every character :P However, this is allowed, as it doesn't affect the program, since all bytes aside from `;#` are ignored.

Comment: How do you run this? I'm trying to execute this and it doesn't terminate. Is it not supposed to?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's waiting for input. See the `getchar()`?

Comment: Yes, but after I provide input, it prints, and still doesn't terminate. That's what I mean.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It terminates upon EOF.

Comment: Ah, got it. I had to use `echo 'Hello, World!' | ./test` rather than typing it during execution.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You can type it during execution, just hit Ctrl+D at the end (assuming you're on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 27 bytes

```
c;AO;~(c=G);J"#"))Wc--)J";"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 19 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @MickyT!*

```
i.#';UoU^!.$U@?(';o
```

on a cube:

```
    i .
    # '
; U o U ^ ! . $
U @ ? ( ' ; o .
    . .
    . .
```

this version is much cleverer than the prior one (my version) with moving the instruction pointer around, using `U` (left-hand u-turn) and the way the adjacencies on the cube to loop and produce the correct output. Explanation to follow.

#### Old Version, 24 bytes:

```
..@.;i?...>;'(/!.;o;W'.#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@6@n56BnnWmvp6dnZ62uoa@oZ51vHa6up/z/v7UyAA) and [Watch it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIC4gLgogICAgQCAuCjsgaSA/IC4gLiAuID4gOwonICggLyAhIC4gOyBvIDsKICAgIFcgJwogICAgLiAjCg==&input=OyM=&speed=100) (the latter might be really slow)

Since this question had a relatively simple I/O scheme, I figured this would be a good fit for a Cubix solution. I still spent a few days trying to solve it, though. The breakthrough was when I tried using `!`, which skips the next instruction if the top of the stack is truthy (not zero, I think), enabling something like a `while` loop.

Cubified:

```
    . .
    @ .
; i ? . . . > ;
' ( / ! . ; o ;
    W '
    . #
```

The instruction pointer starts at the top left corner of the leftmost face, pointing east. Here's the code:

Outer loop:

```
; - pop the top item off the stack. does nothing at the beginning since the stack is empty.
i - read in the ascii character as an integer. Reads -1 at end of input.
? - turns right if the top of the stack is positive, and left if negative.
@ - if negative (end of input), ends the program
/ - mirrors the direction pointer (swapping S<->W and N<->E), entering the inner loop
```

Inner loop:

```
( - decrements the top of the stack (the ascii value of the input)
' - pushes the next char
; - the semicolon
o - outputs as a char
; - pops the top of the stack
! - ignores the next instruction if the top of the stack is not zero
```

then when the appropriate number of `;` have been printed,

```
/ - the IP is moving W, so it now switches S
W - move the IP left
' - push the next char
# - pushes this char
o - prints #
> - points the IP east
; - pop the top of the stack
```

and then returns to the top of the outer loop.

Comment: I have had a crack at remove some of the no-ops in your code.  I managed to trim of a few bytes for `i.#';UoU^!.$U@?(';o`.  It gets a bit messy in there, but it works

Comment: I must admit, I'm impressed! I'll have to take these ideas into consideration for future cubix submissions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 18 bytes

```
&ir[[";"o1-]"#"op]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tsyg6WslaKd9QN1ZJWSm/IPb/f2vygTIxagA)

Comment: Unfortunately your language seems to be newer than the challenge post. You should mark it as "non competing". Great answer though!

Comment: @kalsowerus I believe we have [a consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges) against this.

Comment: @LirycLy Oh, I must have missed that. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 11 bytes

```
&([#;]##)&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fTSNa2TpWWVlTzeH///@JSQA)

Ooh, moderately golfy

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

Edit: -2 bytes thanks to James Holderness

```
#;"~1+:!#@_>1#\-#,: #\_$$,
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X9laqc5Q20pR2SHezlA5RldZx0pBOSZeRUXn/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

#### How it works

```
#;"          Adds # and ; to the stack
   ~1+:!#@_  Gets the input and dupes it. Ends if the input is eof
           >1#\-#,: #\_ Prints a semi-colon until the input byte reaches 0
                       $$, Prints the ending hash and loops back round
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 12 bytes

```
@$:59'.;35'.
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/99BxcrUUl3P2thUXe////9Kjk7OSgA)**

This prints each character of the `;#` code on a newline. To condense the code, simply prepend `N` to the program to remove the printing delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 49 bytes

```kotlin
{it.map{('a'-97..it).map{print(';')}
print('#')}}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
        {
            it.map {
                ('a'-97..it).map { print(';') }
                print('#')
            }
        }
```

### Test

```kotlin
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.PrintStream

/**
 * @author James Tapsell
 */
var o: (String) -> Unit =
{it.map{('a'-97..it).map{print(';')}
print('#')}}

data class Test(val input: String, val output: String)

val tests = listOf(
        Test("Hello, World!", ";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#"),
        Test("ABC", ";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#"),
        Test(";#", ";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#")
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    tests.forEach {
        val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        System.setOut(PrintStream(out))
        o(it.input)
        val text = String(out.toByteArray())
        if (text != it.output) {
            throw AssertionError()
        }
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##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)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ｃ;×#］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjQzJTNCJUQ3JTIzJXVGRjNE,i=JTIySGVsbG8lMkMlMjBXb3JsZCUyMSUyMg__,v=2)

Explanation:

```
{    ] map over the characters of the input
 c     convert the character to its unicode codepoint
  ;×   repeat ";" that many times
    #  push "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 18 bytes

```
L^,€O59C€*"#"€Ω+BF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/98nTudR0xp/U0tnIKWlpKwEpM6t1HZy@6@Sk5iblJKoYGin5OjkrMTlz4Uk4pGak5OvoxCeX5STogiU@w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>7</s></sup> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç`5≡Tf
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=876035f05466&i=%22Hello,+World%21%22%0A%22ABC%22%0A%22%3B%23%22&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `Ks`, <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*<s>-1</s> -2 thanks to Aaron Miller*

```
\;*\#+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ks&code=%5C%3B*%5C%23%2B&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

```
\;*\#+    # Full program
          # Vectorized: Replace each...
          # (K flag) ordinal character in (implicit) input...
\;        # with the character `;`...
  *       # repeated that many times, and...
   \#+    # add the character `#`
          # (s flag) Concatenate results and output
```

Comment: [7 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ks&code=%C6%9B%5C%3B*%5C%23%2B&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Comment: [6 bytes because vectorising](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ks&code=%5C%3B*%5C%23%2B&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 56 bytes

```
=CONCAT(REPT(";",CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))&"#")
```

Could be 8 bytes shorter to output an array of cells ending with #.

### VBA (immediate window), 73 bytes

```
d="":for i=1to len([a1]):d=d &string(asc(mid([a1],i,1)),";") &"#":next:?d
```

Comment: You can get the VBA version down to 70 bytes as `d="":for i=1to[len(a1)]:d=d+string(asc(mid([a1],i,1)),";")+"#":next:?d`

Answer (score 0):

## C (72 bytes)

```
main(c){while((c=getchar())!=-1){while(c--)putchar(';');putchar('#');}}
```

Comment: You could probably write `>-1` rather than `!=-1` to save a byte. Also, `printf` is shorter than `putchar` (and `puts` would be shorter still; you'd put a lot of stray newlines in the output, but those are specified as ignored).

Comment: Why community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 28 charcters

```
?=@repeat{@char-int{?};\;}\#
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '?=@repeat{@char-int{?};\;}\#' <<< 'Hello, World!' | gema '\A=@set{a;0};\;=@incr{a};\#=@int-char{@mod{$a;127}}@set{a;0};?='
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 36 bytes

```
[_l;||[asc(_sA,a,1|)|Z=Z+@;`]Z=Z+@#`
```

Explanation

```
[_l;||        FOR a = 1 to LEN(A$) # A$ is read from the vmd line
[asc(...)     FOR b = 1 to the ASCII value of
   _sA,a,1|     The next char of A$
Z=Z+@;`       Add the increment instruction to Z$
]         NEXT increment instruction
Z=Z+@#`       When all incrementers are added, issue a print-command
              NEXT for the outer FOR loop is added inplicitly at EOF
              Z$ is printed implicitly at EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 91 bytes

```
import(."fmt";."strings")
func f(s string){for _,c:=range s{Print(Repeat(";",int(c))+"#")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#fY27DsIwDEX3foUxiyOqfgAVA3RhRCwsSCgKSVWRR5WEqcq3h6Qw483n2vfMXLz4KMHwyebJzM5H6lCZiH2HIfrJjgFZo95WgKIAX8QW5Tw8WrE/eG7Le1guhUe6ylnySNhjW1fB2A63yFLKa0O1EIOlgTKK8Cy1di3cnNfPTdFUvBZpS3i3P1IOj6fhX9wXR5PyBw)

### Explanation

```
import( . "fmt"                     // fmt import to print stuff out
        . "strings"                 // strings import for string manipulation
)                                   // the dots import into the global namespace

func transpile(str string) {        // function that takes a string argument
    for _, char := range str {      // iterate over the runes (characters) in str
        Print(                      // print x without newline where x is...
              Repeat(";",           // ...";" repeated y times where y is... 
                     int(char)) +   // ...the ASCII integer of the rune and...
              "#")                  // ..."#" to end it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 48 bytes

```
00000000: 53d0 80c3 cf53 d080 a078 2080 7b23 8100  SÐ.ÃÏSÐ. x .{#..
00000010: 0020 8088 40a0 5f4c d3d0 80a3 8101 2080  . ..@ _LÓÐ.£.. .
00000020: b553 5080 a05f 2080 ad8b 2381 020a 3b23  µSP. _ ...#...;#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc4xCsIwFMbx3VN80lUer0lDgy6ODg5CB8eSNO1ULDgJjh5AwQsUPIMXaA5WE9MsL4S8H3/bmss883K2UNIxNDcSTackHGuG4VJDxFtphYTOmYHKv8g//DPOabyB7hnRKjF5gJhFhLRGwYahuqKBS7j5G3kiQSDaT2N99O9IfSg8LI4IjlUhQ6UM1aUd47SFkDpH@GIgYxWmb3UKJXXgKKTQLpvnQ9v3wwbn4dq79Q8)

#### Equivalent JavaScript (ES6):

```
[..._.join("\n")].map((c)=>";".repeat(c.charCodeAt())+"#");
```

#### Explanation

Taking multiline standard input as an array of string lines in `_`, it first joins them with `\n` and spreads the resulting string into an array of characters, which is then mapped like in [@Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122157/42091).

The difference is, it outputs the raw array of `;#` strings that represent each character, but because the language specification will ignore all of the following characters: `[]' ,` this is valid behavior.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 54 + 18 = 72 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;
s=>string.Join("",s.Select(c=>new string(';',c)+"#"));
```

#### Ungolfed full program and explanation

```
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Func<string, string> f =
            s => string.Join("",       //4. Join the results separated by an empty string and implicitly return
                s.Select(c =>          //1. For each character in the input
                    new string(';', c) //2. Implicitly convert the character to an int with the ASCII-Code and create a new string with that many ;
                    + "#"));           //3. Add a #

        System.Console.WriteLine(f(";#"));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f("ABC"));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
ṁȯ`:'#R';c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxhPrE6zUlYPUrZP///@vZK2sBAA)

#### Ungolfed/Explained

```
ṁȯ          -- map function and concatenate result
         c  --   ASCII order of element times
      R';   --   repeat ';' and
  `:'#      --   append '#'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>50</s> 32 bytes

This is a direct port of my Husk answer:

```hs
((\n->(';'<$['\1'..n])++"#")=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0MjJk/XTkPdWt1GJVo9xlBdTy8vVlNbW0lZSdPWxkbzf25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZFPnoKeQpoCUEIhPbXEOT@vJDWvpPi/tfK/5LScxPTi/7oRzgEBAA)

Thanks @Laikoni for saving me 18 bytes!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
[print(''.join((';'*ord(i)+'#')for i in input()))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7qgKDOvRENdXS8rPzNPQ0PdWl0rvyhFI1NTW11ZXTMtv0ghUyEzD4gKSks0NDU1YxX@/3dxdQMA)

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 24 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{,["#"sv(7h$x)#'";"]"#"}
```

**Explanation:**

`q` is interpreted right-to left. We cast the input to it's ASCII values, thus `"Hello, World!"` becomes `72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33`. We then take this many of the `;` character, which gives us a list of lists. These lists are joined together with `#`, then we a `#` on the end to terminate the string.

```
{,["#"sv(7h$x)#'";"]"#"} / the solution
{                      } / lambda function
 ,[                ]"#"  / concatenate with "#"
              #'         / apply each-left take (#) each-right
                ";"      / the right (the character ;)
        (7h$x)           / the left (input cast to ASCII values)
   "#"sv                 / join these lists back together with "#"
```

**Bonus:**

Could save 1 byte moving the cast outside the function, but that's a bit underhand:

```
{,["#"sv x#'";"]"#"}7h$
```

Taking inspiration from the APL solution and the above yields a 22 byte solution:

```
{raze(x#'";"),'"#"}7h$
```

which becomes 20 bytes in `k`

```
{,/(x#'";"),'"#"}7h$
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＦＳ⁺×;℅ι#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLDkBADADQq1RtWsYJXICdxMJCLCbjmzRGarh@easXdq8hejFbowK15/WkPulxbsQM3Z9EJRWENToIu9LB7ABzZK7NRmwWkehgiCpzhpNVr1W3fA)

#### Explanation (for those too lazy to click the link)

```
Ｆ         For
 Ｓ        each character in next input as string
   ⁺    #  Append "#"
    × ℅ι   Multiply (repeat) by the character code of i (loop variable)
     ;     ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 71 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(map'list(lambda(x)(format t"~v,,,v<~>#"(char-code x)#\;))s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r/FfIycxNyklUaNYUyM3sUAdKFoCE6rQ1EjLL8pNLFEoUaor09HRKbOps1NW0kjOSCzSTc5PSVWo0FSOsdbULNbU/K9krayk@R8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 90 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
T	N LEN(1) . L REM . N :F(END)
	&ALPHABET L @X
	OUTPUT =DUPL(';',X) '#' :(T)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hCsEyPRx9dMw1FTQU/BRCHL1BdJ@ClZuGq5@LppcnGqOPgEejk6uIUBJhwguTv/QEKA2BVuX0AAfDXVrdZ0ITQV1ZXUFK40QTS6glv//PVJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFAE)

```
	N =INPUT			;* read input
T	N LEN(1) . L REM . N :F(END)	;* set L to the first character, N to the REMainder, and
					;* if there is no match (N is empty), goto END
	&ALPHABET L @X			;* @ssign X with the value of the match of L inside &ALPHABET (all ASCII chars)
	OUTPUT =DUPL(';',X) '#' :(T)	;* set OUTPUT to ';' duplicated X times concatenated with '#', and a newline
					;* then goto T
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 11 bytes

```
iEHr{R`;`#r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9PVo6g6KME6Qbno/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

#### How it works

```
iEHr{R`;`#r

i            Input n as char
 EH          If EOF, print stack contents as chars (from top) and exit

             Stack content                     [x y z... n]
   r{        Reverse the whole stack except n  [...z y x n]
     R`;     Pop n and push that many ';'s     [...z y x ;...;]
        `#   Push '#'                          [...z y x ;...; #]
          r  Reverse stack                     [# ;...; x y z...]
             Repeat indefinitely
```

The `r...r` structure makes the invariant that the stack content is the desired string reversed.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 23 Bytes

Nothing special.

```
,([:,&'#'#&';')"0 u:inv
```

#### Explanation:

```
,([:,&'#'#&';')"0 u:inv
                  u:inv   | Convert string to code points
 (            )"0         | For each item:
  [:,&'#'#&';'            | Repeat ';' n times and append #
,                         | Ravel the resulting character array
```

Note that the result contains lots of whitespace, since arrays have to be rectangular.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 63 bytes

```java
c->{var s="";for(var d:c){for(;d-->0;)s+=";";s+="#";}return s;}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##RY8xb8MgEIVn/CuudAFFtjoXOVLkJRk6ZehQdaCAU1IM0YEtRZZ/uwtNlUx373T3vXtnOcn6rH/Wy/jlrALlZIzwJq2HuSLWJ4O9VAa64CeDWZUxOSa0/gQ9hmF37A4Hpr4lfnyCjMpaLiqyVOQfGJNMuUzBahgylt1uyzKeIv/DPeDq3rWwqno7TxIhtpSKPiArQr8qPhchdF1vXwSPm5YKKkp5pmJBk0b0EMWyEiLKr9eYzNCEMTWX7JycZ3eX5pGA7o1zAd4DOv1EmxS6HGmHKK@M81ukZf0F).

Ungolfed version:

```java
c -> { // lambda taking a char[] as argument and returning a String
    var s = ""; // the output String
    for(var d : c) { // iterate over all the input chars
        for(; d-- > 0 ;) // as many times as the ASCII value of the current char
            s += ";";    // append ";" to the program to compute the character
        s += "#"; // append "#" to output the character
    }
    return s; // return the finished program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 13 bytes

```
~W$:ki@j";#"~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/78uXMUqO9MhS8laWanu/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 21 bytes

```
I~sL(";"si/B*P"#"P!i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/37Ou2EdDyVqpOFPfSStASVkpQDFT8/9/pZCMVIXC0szkbIWkovzyPIW0/AqFrNLcgmKF/LLUIgWgZoWcxKpKhZT8dCUA)

**Explanation:**

```
I~s                   - Get input and store in the variable s
   L(               ) - Loop until the top of stack equals the length of s
     ";"              - Push the string ";"
        si/           - Return the character of string s at position i
           B          - Return the ASCII code of the character
            *P        - Multiply ";" by the ASCII code and print
              "#"P    - Push the string "#" and print
                  !i  - Increment i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 94 bytes

```pascal
var c:char;i:word;begin repeat read(c);for i:=1to ord(c)do write(';');write('#')until eof end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxCsMwDAC/IsjgeGggq0Ufo8pyKgiWUd3k@a6HTncc1@jDdD5K4zEucuDEb3LUdJtnfMmhFVyaUJ@gvHLEYg6anns3mM8s2eB27bIGDBH/uoT4rV1PECsgNW9j4PID)

Assumes non-empty input.

Comment: You do not need to declare and use an _additional_ integer variable. You can re‑use your `char` variable: `var c:char;begin repeat read(c);for c:=^Ato c do write(';');write('#')until eof end.`

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (Excel) 82 Bytes

I really think this challenge should've been scored in the length of your program after it is converted into ;#. I would score 6769 characters (including newlines)

```vb
Function d(e)
  For i=1To Len(e)
    d=d &String(Asc(Mid(e,i,1)),";") &"#"
  Next
End Function
```

*Note: the leading spaces aren't needed, just make it more read-able, not that I should be worried about that... just look at the output from this thing!!!*

**Un-golfed With Comments:**

```vb
Function toSemiHash(translate)
    'For 1 to the length of the string
    For i = 1 To Len(translate)
        'Append a semicolon the char-code number of times along with a hash
        fromSemiHash = fromSemiHash & String(Asc(Mid(translate, i, 1)), ";") & "#"
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 75 Bytes

This shorter then the parser I wrote for it.

**Generator**

```
function g($s){foreach(str_split($s)as$a)echo str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#';}
```

You can test it like this:

```
$strings = [
    'Hello, World!',
    ';#',
    '!'
];

foreach($strings as $s){
    g($s); echo "\n\n";
}

function g($s){foreach(str_split($s)as$a){echo str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#';}}
```

**Parser (second attempt)**

The one from my first attempt should work fine as well. This one is shorter, so well just use it to verify that the generator works correctly.

```
function f($s){foreach(split('#',$s)as$a)echo!$a?'':chr(substr_count($a,';')%127);}
```

You can test both like this:

```
//turn of warning message or set in PHP.ini
error_reporting(0);
$s = "Hello, World!";

function g($s){foreach(str_split($s)as$a)echo str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#';}
function f($s){foreach(split('#',$s)as$a)echo!$a?'':chr(substr_count($a,';')%127);}

//output buffer the generator
ob_start();
    g($s);
$s=ob_get_clean();
f($s);
```

Output

```
 Hello, World!
```

[Test both of them](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bb1d9c7fdb6fa39cfb26635a72c15a136d96236)

A few things to note:

- Because neither one return information, we can capture the output by using output buffering.

  - We could also put it a file, use `$argv[1]` for input, remove the function calls, add the shebang `#!/bin/env php` and run it from the terminal.  Which would cut it down to around something like `65`. Then we could just pipe that into the other script.  So :-P
- Because the parser is old, we have to use PHP < 7 for it.  Don't worry our dev team is currently working hard on a patch to make it compatible with PHP7,(just change split to explode). They should have it done sometime in the spring after they quite code golfing and get back to work!

**Lastly**

My first attempt at a parser was recursive, so I thought it only fitting I make a generator that is also recursive.  Unfortunately as with the first one, it's longer  `89 bytes`.

```
 function g($s,$i,$r){echo''==($a=$s[$i])?$r:g($s,++$i,$r.=str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#');}
```

You can test it with the same code above:

```
error_reporting(0);
$s = "Hello, World!";

//function g($s){foreach(str_split($s)as$a)echo str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#';}
function f($s){foreach(split('#',$s)as$a)echo!$a?'':chr(substr_count($a,';')%127);}

//recursive
function h($s,$i,$r){echo''==($a=$s[$i])?$r:h($s,++$i,$r.=str_repeat(';',ord($a)).'#');}

//output buffer the generator
ob_start();
   // g($s);
   h($s,0,'');
$s=ob_get_clean();
f($s);
```

[Recursive Generator](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbbd68b917debb271f460569e2ed12081ee0ca1c)

Things that didn't make the cut

```
  //parser 98 bytes, strtok + do while
  function p($s){$f=strtok;$a=$f($s,'#');do{echo chr(substr_count($a,';')%127);}while($a=$f('#'));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 48 bytes

```
+++++++[>+++++>++++++++<<-]>>+++>,[[-<.>]<<.>>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKi7cCUHZSrbWOjG2sH4tnpREfr2ujZxdoACTud2P//PVJzcvIVwvOLclIUAQ)

#### How it works

```
+++++++[>+++++>++++++++<<-]>>+++>       'write ; and # onto the tape
,[                                      'read input as ascii values and loop
    [-<.>]                              'decrement input 1 and write ; then repeat until 0
    <<.>>                               'write #
,]                                      'read input as ascii values and loop
```

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1o32kbbTtdOV1fXJtZOWzvWxsZGW9tGJzpa107PJtZGz04n9v9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFAA "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
[:,[:('#',~#&';')"+3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgEETR3lNMJGEgEmJCKFziSegxsbfUq69LMdV/c@uawYFTiIRXsMOmXVKXQMf0Oc/GuG7FP6JRB9gcl8seMBVKnaQeJnwOE0WL0/w)

```
[:,(35,~#&59)"+&.(3&u:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgEETR3lNMJGEgEmJCKFziSegxsbfUq69LMdV/c@uawYFTiIRXsMOmXVIoNX3O1yOum8@h@EeiRh1gc1wue8BUl0DHCdlocjKL0/w)

Posting since [the existing J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162369/78410) is incorrect.

#### How it works

```
[:,[:('#',~#&';')"+3&u:
                   3&u:  Convert to ASCII value
     (          )"+      Apply to each number...
           #&';'           Convert to that many ';'s
      '#',~                and add '#' to the right
   [:                    Treat the above as monadic fork
  ,                      Ravel; flatten the multidimensional array
[:                       Treat the above as monadic fork

[:,(35,~#&59)"+&.(3&u:)
              f&.g       Apply g, f, then inverse of g...
                 (3&u:)    g: convert to ASCII value
   (        )"+            f: apply to each number...
        #&59                 convert to that many 59's (charcode of ';')
    35,~                     and add 35 to the right (charcode of '#')
[:,                      Ravel the result
```

Both use the `"+` trick to avoid numeric literal problem.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 82 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_OUTER_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_HASTAG][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S S S T  T   T   S T T   N
_Push_59_;][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_HASHTAG][S S S T  S S S T T   N
_Push_35_#][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_OUTER_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYiAmEuBk4tTgZOTE8YF8UBskLACJ4jBCZLn4uSCynMpQBWA5WDiXP//e6Tm5OTrKITnF@WkKAIA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start OUTER_LOOP:
  Integer c = read character from STDIN
  Start INNER_LOOP:
    If(c == 0):
      Jump to function HASHTAG
    c = c - 1
    Print ";" to STDOUT
    Go to next iteration of INNER_LOOP

function HASHTAG:
  Print "#" to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of OUTER_LOOP
```

Note: All characters read from STDIN in Whitespace are automatically stored in the heap as their code-point values.

Answer (score 0):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 27 bytes

```
}o" i# :" }]@_!}|{:" [; o".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/782X0khU1nBSkmhNtYhXrG2phrIjLZWyFfS@/8/MSkZAA)

I'm sure a shorter solution exists, given this has 6 no-ops. This prints a null byte to begin with

#### Explanation:

```
}o       Print a null byte
    i  :  }]  ! |{     Get a character of input and check if it is EOF
                   "  ; o"   If it is not, print a ;
               }| :  [       Decrement the counter and check again
                   Once the counter hits zero exit the loop
            @_    If the value was -1 (EOF) exit
           ]  !   Otherwise execute some garbage
 o" i#  "         Print a # and get the next character of input
```

Answer (score 0):

### W `j` `d`, 7 bytes

The input format is `[['a','b',..]]`

```
◘Pp½h#û
```

### Explanation

Uncompressed:

```
C';*'#+M
```

````
       M % For every item in the input:
C        % Convert to a character
 ';*     % Repeat ; ASCII codepoint times
    '#+  % Append a #

Flag:j   % Join without newline
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
{";"*"#"}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1rJWklLSVmpVvX/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 13 bytes

```
m{'#j**';j.*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f8/t1pdOUtLS906S0@r9v9/j9ScnHwA)

```
m{      # For each char in string (implicit concat)
  '#    # Push #
  j**   # Find ord(char)
  ';j.* # That many ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 44 bytes

```perl6
say $*IN.slurp.ords.map(';'x*).join('#'),'#'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBRcvTT684p7SoQC@/KKVYLzexQEPdWr1CS1MvKz8zT0NdWV1TB0j8/5@RmpOTr1CeX5SToggA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>52</s> 49 + 8 = 57 bytes

`-lordchr` command-line parameter to import the ORDCHR extension.

```
BEGIN{RS=".|"}{for(;i++<ord(RT);)s=s";"}i=$0=s"#"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9GqbY6Lb9IwzpTW9smvyhFIyhE01qz2LZYyVqpNtNWxQDIUlb6/99a@V9@QUlmfl7xf90coLrkjCIA)

This code roams the input one character at a time, and prints as many `;` as needed, and a `#` between characters. To print everything in one line, just put `ORS=""` inside the brackets of the `BEGIN` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 57 bytes

```lua
(...):gsub('.',load'print((";"):rep((...):byte()).."#")')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P9fQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUNdT10nJz8xRb2gKDOvRENDyVpJ06ootUADoiapsiRVQ1NTT09JWUlTXfP///8eqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKAA)

Essentially grabs the byte value of each character and repeats `;` that many times, followed by a `#` and a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
C';×'#+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhYrnNWtD09XV9ZeUpyUXAwVXLDUIzUnJx_CAQA)

##### Explanation

```
C';×'#+  # Implicit input
C        # Cast to ordinals
 ';×     # Repeat ";" that many times
    '#+  # Append "#" to each
         # Implicit output, joined
```

Answer (score -1):

### C, 51 bytes

```
c;main(){for(;c||~(c=getchar());puts("#;"+!!--c));}
```

Outputs lots of extra newlines, and an extra `;` at the end, but neither of those affect the output of the `;#` program, so it should be fine.

Using puts was suggested by ais523 in a comment: [Make a ;# transpiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122139/make-a-transpiler#comment299719_122162).

`~(x)` is a shorter way to write `(x)!=-1`.

`"#;"+!!--c` is a pointer arithmetic equivalent of `--c?";":"#;"`.