# Be big more often

Tags: code-golf, random, open-ended-function

#### [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89621/random-golf-of-the-day-7-a-distinctly-random-character)

You are a manager at a large number factory. You want to show everyone your business is doing well, by showing randomly chosen samples. Unfortunately, your business is not doing that well. But luckily, you have a bit of ingenuity...

---

Write a program or function that when given an array of unique, positive numbers, which may include floats, returns a random number from the array, with **bigger numbers having a higher probability of being chosen \$\left(a_n > a_m \implies P(a_n) > P(a_m)\right)\$**, **no two numbers being chosen with the same probability \$\left(P(a_n) \not = P(a_m)\right)\$**, and **all numbers having a non-zero chance of being chosen \$\left(P(a_n) \not = 0\right)\$**. Anyways, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: I noticed that many (most?) of the answers so far ( including one of mine) only meet the ‘ no two numbers being chosen with the same probability ‘ criterion if the input is restricted to integers.  Can you clarify if this is Ok, or otherwise indicate that we should update our (invalid) answers…?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I believe they're valid. For answers using weights, the numbers 2.7 and 2.7000000001 may look like they do not obey that rule, but in reality they do. The probabilities are extremely close together, but are not equal, so no rules have been broken.

Comment: I was thinking of answers like my last one that repeat each number in the list a certain (integer) number of times, and then pick one at random.  In my case, [1,2,2.7,3] would become [1,2,2,2.7,2.7,3,3,3], so 2 & 2.7 would have the same probaability.  I think that the Charcoal, Vyxal, J, Ruby, Factor, and Julia answers all use a variant of this, as well as my (last) R answer.

Comment: Why two close votes?

Comment: See my comment above with currently 12 up-arrows.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen so closing my challenge because of other people's mistakes?

Answer (score 25):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 41 bytes

```python
lambda l:choices(l,l)
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3NXMSc5NSEhVyrJIz8jOTU4s1cnRyNLnSivJzFYoS81KAVGZuQX5RiRZEw9aCosy8Eo00jWhDHSMdYx0THdNYTU2I3IIFEBoA) or [run it 100000 times](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3NXMSc5NSEhVyrJIz8jOTU4s1cnRyNLnSivJzFYoS81KAVGZuQX5RiRZUQxBYKjk_Jyc1uSQzP68YJs9VUJSZV6LhnF-aV5JapBGdphFtqGOkY6xjomMaqxltEJuWX6QQr5CZBzI3PVXD0AAENGM1NSEmL1gAoQE)

Uses the list itself as the weights.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer thanks! Nice challenge btw.

Comment: Very good. This one even has a level of plausible deniability ("Oops, I must have misremembered the syntax of `choices`, sorry").

Answer (score 14):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

(Or 20 bytes in R>=4.1 using `\` instead of `function`)

```r
function(x)-sample(-x,1,,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQlO3ODG3ICdVQ7dCx1BHp0Lzf5mtoZWhAVdJYhJQtDixoCCnUgMkAgY6cJ2ZmmkaZZqamv8B)

The 4th argument of R’s `sample` function is `prob`=“a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled”.

Unfortunately, a “convenience” feature of `sample` changes its behaviour when its first argument is a single positive number, so we need to negate it here to avoid this, and then re-negate the result.

——

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

(Or 24 bytes in R>=4.1 using `\` instead of `function`)

```r
function(x)max(-sample(-x,2,T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjM3sUJDtzgxtyAnVUO3QsdIJ0RT83@ZraGVoQFXSWISULQ4saAgp1IDJAIGOnDdmZppGmWaQPUA)

Return the highest of two random picks.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 64 bytes (also supports negative numbers)

```python
lambda l:sorted(l)[int(len(l)*random()**.5)]
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NYxNCsIwFIT3PUWWeSGV1h8QQRC8gPtapLaJBpL3QpouPIubguidvI2t1dnMMMN895e_xSth_9Db47OLOl2_d7Zy56ZidtNSiKrhFgqDkVuFQxShwoYcByFmKygTHcixqWPG-eEhfpzDd6rJWlVHQ9j-98SHkbenDqMKvNC8SHOZyblcyGUJmgI7MYMj9aJ4no2CEmDi9v3kHw)

### Explanation

Sort the list, the pick a random element.
The square root biases the result towards the end of the list.

Comment: Interesting solution! +1

Answer (score 8):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 8 bytes

```
#~{~1?+/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsUK5rrrO0F5bH8LdpMmVmpyRr5CmYKhgpGCsYKJgCpFYsABCAwA)

- `1?+/` Sum the numbers and then choose a random index between 0 and the sum
- `#~{~` Take that index from a new array formed by duplicating each number as many times as itself.  Eg, `#~ 1 2 3` gives `1 2 2 3 3 3`, and we choose a random index from the interval \$[0,6)\$.

Answer (score 7):

## WolframLanguage, <strike>63</strike> 48 bytes

*Thanks to att* for shaving of 15

```
Sort[#][[Floor@Log2[Random[](2^Tr[1^#]2-3)+2]]]&
```

Original answer:

```
f[r_]:=Sort[r][[Floor@Log[2,RandomReal[{2,2^(Length@r+1)-1}]]]]
```

Sorts the array and picks a random number between `2` and `2^(l+1)-1`, where `l` is the length of the list. Then takes the logarithm to get the array index. This gives each number a twice as high probability to be chosen as the previous one.

### Example

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

For a run of 2*10^7 repetitions:

`{{1, 19562}, {2, 39068}, {3, 78145}, {4, 156309}, {5, 313362}, {6,  625087}, {7, 1249297}, {8, 2504498}, {9, 5005805}, {10, 10008867}}`

[image]

Comment: An interesting answer. +1

Comment: `[[]]` has higher precedence than `@`

Comment: @att fixed it...

Comment: [48](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzi/qCRaOTY62i0nP7/IwSc/3Sg6KDEvJT83OlbDKC6kKNowTjnWSNdYU9soNjZW7X@OLUQ6ODG3ICfVAchJT3UwNOAKKMrMK3HIgdLeqZUgkx2c80vzSoodQhKTclKj0xxydAwNgCD2PwA)

Comment: Since the inputs are positive and distinct, how about `RandomChoice[#->#]&`?

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort()[a.length*Math.random()**.5|0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DsIwDADQnVNkjKNg8WnZgsTCxgmqDlabtqBgIyeCInH38N6D3pQHvb/KlmWMdQqVwpkwixYLHWGKPJfF3agsqMSjPC04h@1v19fVBMPxY65JqJyaiyp9bbf3B3/0jW972AzCWVLEJLOd7ApQ/w) or [run it 100000 times](https://tio.run/##Hcy/DoIwEMfxnae4sQVtQMFBrImLm09AGC78N7VnSqMY5Nlr5YZPbvl97/jCsTLD02411Y1rpUN5RjGSsYwXKFSjO9uHN7S9MKhrejAehiL7xqUjkDAnR4g3sFvdr6armXfJg5YMsEHGOQynJP6f/6KIwzz5dct084arIrSH9GIMfliR@JpP@Y6PlJznQMVUQiQhWYKK9EiqEYo6Rtz9AA)

Takes an `Float64Array` (so the sorting works properly). Port of bsoelch's Python answer. 
[+10 bytes](https://tio.run/##DccxDoMwDADAva/waEeJRZE6pj/oCxCDgQCt0rhKooqhf09ZTrqXfKXM@fmpLukS2uqb@Ltw0VwRxU50zk00CMeQtrqbh9Sds6RF30jG8O3Xje0AD4PrLbirhc7CaT9eZk1FY@CoG654ELU/) to take a regular array.

Comment: Wow this even beats the current JavaScript answer!

Comment: @Arnauld am I allowed to take an `Int32Array`? Because if I am then we don't need to change the code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/J7VEIbGoyFDBViHaXEfBQkfBUkfB0ACIDYHYKFZBX18hL78oNzEHpCyxkis5P684PydVLyc/XQOkUa84v6hEQ1OTiwtqlBHQqLzUcgXPvBJjI0eQHg2sJmuCjEYoQjfYCGbw//8A "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @MTN my challenge specs just say an array, so an Int32Array might be ok, but in theory it should be able to work for any positive number.

Comment: Change the first TIO to not use negative numbers, because the sorting doesn't work properly for them.

Comment: @noodleman done, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
℅?℅∴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLihIU/4oSF4oi0IiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzLDQsNSwxMF0iXQ==)

Return the highest of two random picks

```
℅       # Random choice of single item from input array
 ?      # Input (again)
  ℅     # Random choice of single item from this
    ∴   # Maximum of these two values
```

Comment: +1 for your first Vyxal programme!

Comment: Ayo welcome to Vyxal! Very cool!

Comment: Your first solution seems to have a 0 probability to return the smallest element? Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @ATaco - Yes, you're right, I realised that in the car this morning.  I'm rolling-back.  Oh, well...  Thanks for spotting.

Comment: @ATaco - fixed now (I think)

Comment: Yes fixed - by choosing twice uniformly and taking the maximum of the two the probability of picking the \$a^{\text{th}}\$ most minor of \$n\$ numbers is \$\frac{2a-1}{n^2}\$. e.g. \$P(3^{\text{rd}}\text{ smallest of }8)=\frac{5}{64}\$.

Comment: @lyxαl - (unrelated to this post but pinging you here).- I tried to message you under the 'golfing class...' meta post, but I don't think you got it as you aren't a commenter...  Anyway, please could you update the query and code used for this (='golfing class' ranking).  I'm fascinated, but can't reproduce the results you're posting...  Thanks!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I made a chat room for discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148320/elo-discussion-room-2

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```ruby
->l{(l+l).sample(2).max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCsMgEEDRvafIUul0cAyFbuxFxEUaEghqK00CNsazG5ou/4P/WZ/fOup6ffjM/cULnLsQ/cCVwNClUp02BApauMEdqAVFlpHEZQrDnGMzGmcLY5vmhEhSyt8W859j487a024SbNi/19fCk7ClHg)

Thanks to Dominic van Essen for -4 bytes and the idea to get to -8.

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoMwEADveYVHhXXJKoVe0o@EHFQUSpIaaoRozNtTUXqbGZjv2m95Erl@mSgNLp11ZoQ/KLRdSFkLSdBACw94ArXQkGLE0b/tuERXTFKrxNguSkIkznl1bi7e2RX6siMcMsCOw7x@fBkqlfIP) porting my 2nd R answer, and works with non-integers...  (my first Ruby program...)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 3 bytes

```
X»X
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FksiDu2OWFKclFwMFVgfrRRtqGOkY6xjomMaqxQLFQYA)

Distribution over 1000 runs: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FksiDu2OWFKclFy8Kfzhru4T2w-3P2pa83DnIp9jMxMgStZHK0Ub6hjpGOuY6JjGKsVCdQIA)

Uses [Dominic van Essen's insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264847/56178): pick a random element (`X`), twice, then take the larger of them (`»`).

Comment: The probability of picking the \$a^{\text{th}}\$ most minor of \$n\$ numbers is \$\frac{2a-1}{n^2}\$. e.g. \$P(3^{\text{rd}}\text{ smallest of }8)=\frac{5}{64}\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＦＡＦι⊞υιＩ‽υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLREQ1NTAczL1FQIKC3O0CjVUcjUtOYKKMrMK9FwTiwu0QhKzEvJz9Uo1dTUtP7/PzraUEfBSEfBWEfBJDb2v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＡ
```

Loop over the input numbers.

```
Ｆι⊞υι
```

Push each number that many times to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｉ‽υ
```

Output a random number from that list.

8 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
Ｉ‽ΣＥＡＥιι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjeNAooy80o0nBOLSzSCEvNS8nM1gktzNXwTCzQ88wpKSzQ0dRRAnEwdhUxNMLBeUpyUXAzVvzxaSbcsRyl2XXS0oY6CkY6CsY6CSWwsRBIA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ａ       Input list
   Ｅ        Map over elements
      ι     Current element
     Ｅ      Map over implicit range
       ι    Outer element
  Σ         Flatten
 ‽          Random element
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

A port of @JoyalMathew's JavaScript answer in straight succinct Charcoal is only 6 bytes:

```
Ｉ⌈∨Φθ‽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9jaGFyY29hbP//77yp4oyI4oiozqbOuOKAvf//W1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0XV0) Explanation:

```
    θ   Input list
   Φ    Filtered by
     ‽  Random coin flip
  ∨     If empty then implicitly use input list
 ⌈      Take the maximum
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: Do you mean "a port of [Joyal Matthew's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264841/95126)"...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen With one "t", but yes, wow, I completely jumped to conclusions there.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>b-a).filter(_=>Math.random()<.5)[0]||a[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BTsMwEEXX5BR/OVamVgwUqFJH4gCcIIrQtE3AyI2RYypVtGcPprDpLOYv/ryn@ZCDTNvoPtNiDLt@HuwsthE9hZiIhDfKNpuFKD04n/pIr7Z5kfSuo4y7sCe11kvVVt3pJHnPvk/Yhq8xTbB4jlGOZMyF9VSpuhhCBP0eudxXdY41TJWnRlk6he/i5g9vB2oN45Zxx7hnLBkPjEfGE2PFmelUh9LC1MX52mou1pxXznEKvtc@vJHj/w9b16niPP8A)

Sorts the numbers, filters them randomly, then chooses the largest one.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript very well, but this appears to have a possibility of filtering out the empty list? Or is that covered with the `a.pop()` at the end?

Comment: Yea, it just chooses the largest element if the filtered list is empty.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 13 bytes

```
*.roll(2).max
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMHy3EoFtTQF26WlJWm6Fmu19Iryc3I0jDT1chMrIGI3ba25ihMrFTTSNKINdYx0jHVMdExjNSsqFAwNgEBTLzknsbg4M61SQ0tTrzi_qASotUBDW0uvLDGnNFUTYsiCBRAaAA)

Picks two elements independently and returns the max of the two.

Comment: The probability of picking the \$a^{\text{th}}\$ most minor of \$n\$ numbers is \$\frac{2a-1}{n^2}\$. e.g. \$P(3^{\text{rd}}\text{ smallest of }8)=\frac{5}{64}\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
RandomChoice[#->#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcy/CsIwEMfx3acILThFuK6WSsEXKNUtZjhrQgP5I@l18OljjLnpN9z345BW5ZDMgkkPaUb/Cu66BrMo0Z4urTymKRpPoiG1ETP@vdP54Rte1nALkcY7Pq0S/3RWaIXkHUje5DfZH2oedsoBC5p1ABwAGEWDditYZaz9VEyPxc/O76Ts0xc) Like other languages, the builtin can use weights, so the input can serve as the weights as well. Works with nonnegative real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 35 bytes

```
[ [ dup <array> ] map-flat random ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NYw9CsJAFAb7nOID6wQXDf5iKzY2ok1I8Ug2sGQ3WV5eiiCexGYbc6fcRjBYDQPDvMeKCmk5TI_77XI970HMNHSoNTfaomidN1Zz0ouxRozuwNSUrYNnLTJ4No3gEEVPqB1WSFOoDdZQUEuoFK9PL1W8nRYZMpS9x_H3PyGHIx9XluQ_zOd0LMhaJLOEMPML)

Create n copies of each n, and select one at random (uniformly).

For instance, `{ 5 1 2 }` becomes `{ 5 5 5 5 5 1 2 2 }`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 37 bytes

```
!l=rand([fill.(sort(l),keys(l))...;])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdVFXNsixLzUjSi0zJzcvQ0ivOLSjRyNHWyUyuLgbSmnp6edawmVHF0joKtQrSBnqGOgZ4REBvHchUBRQytDA0MDBT0auwU4nXtFHO4Cooy80py8jSKosFSsZowET2NHAU9WzuF5PzSvBI9DT1bW5Bd0UWxmlArYO4CAA)

sort the list and repeat each element by their index before randomly choosing a number

#### with integers only, 25 bytes

```
!l=rand([fill.(l,l)...;])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjsVc2yLEvNSNKLTMnNy9DRydHI09fT0rGM1IfI3Q3MUbBWiDXWMdIxjuYqAbEMrQwMDAwW9GjuFeF07xRyugqLMvJKcPI2iaLBUrCZMBGiagp6tnUJyfmleiZ6Gnq2tRo6mTnRRrCbUcJgjAA)

directly repeat each number by itself

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ṢxJX
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of distinct floats and outputs a random one.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUVXhH///@PNtQz1VEwNDUwAJMgQkfBQM/QNBYA)** Or see the results of [10,000 runs](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUVXhH/D7dXP9q47sR2EyD/6KQi9///o430THUUjPSMQIQJiDADEYYgwjgWAA).

#### How?

Weights by the count of lesser-or-equal values.

The probability of picking the \$a^{\text{th}}\$ most minor of \$n\$ numbers is \$\frac{2a}{n(n+1)}\$.

For example given `[2.5, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.1, 2.3]` (\$n(n+1)=6(6+1)=42\$):
$$P(2.1)=\frac{1}{21}, P(2.2)=\frac{2}{21}, \cdots , P(2.6)=\frac{6}{21}$$

```
ṢxJX - Link: list of numbers, A
Ṣ    - sort {A} -> [a1, a2, a3, ...]
  J  - indices {A} -> [1, 2, 3, ...]
 x   - {sorted A} times {indices of A} -> [a1, a2, a2, a3, a3, a3, ...]
   X - uniform random choice
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
øḊ℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLDuOG4iuKEhSIsIiIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDVdIl0=)

### Explained

```
øḊ℅­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
øḊ   # ‎⁡Run length decode the input, using the input as both character source and lengths. Basically, zip and run length decode
  ℅  # ‎⁢Choose randomly from that list.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>b-a)[.4/Math.random()|0]||a[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctLDoIwFIXhOau4wzZAbRUnYtmBK2g6uLwUglxTiCEB1l4rZ/DnTL4evzhVrvvM6Uh141vtURcoJnIzY5iUXBdlityI7PTA@SUcjjW9Gd@k3TY00noCDau6gUzgfPRyNDt6Dd3zqCUHrNMyh@6u5H/hxTGHdQm6ZUYFHGRgwVieA5nFQqxB7VFF40RDIwZ6MuL@Bw)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 53 bytes

```javascript
a=>Math.max(...a.map(_=>a[a.length*Math.random()|0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NCoJAFIX3PsVdzmQNTj8Q2fgAQbVoKRIXc3RCHRlFDPPZ7eZZfBw4fJw39timzjTdpj/OWs2ooit2hahwYEIIpNKwp4owRlFmdd4Vq2V3WL9sxfg3SDifLSgY5QmCNWwX7hbuFx6IU@hp64AZFYRgzjL4h5rvcxgHsjWLJclkkkZOwkOw8ZCAr0BOXmrr1paZKG3OLo/7TbSdM3Vu9IdZ@v8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{.s˜Ω
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/Wq/49JxzK///jzbUMdIx0jPXMY4FAA)

Or alternatively, a port of [*@DominicVanEssen*'s second R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264847/52210) is 5 bytes as well:

```
ΩIΩ‚à
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3ErPcysfNcw6vOD//2hDHSMdIz1zHeNYAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
{      # Sort the (implicit) input-list from lowest to highest
 .s    # Pop and push a list of its suffixes
   ˜   # Flatten it
    Ω  # Pop and push a random item from this list
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
Ω      # Push a random item from the (implicit) input-list
 I     # Push the input-list
  Ω    # Pop and push another random item from it
   ‚   # Pair the two together
    à  # Pop and push its maximum
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
‼ww╙
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rw57y8kdTZ/7/H22oY6RjpGeuYxwLAA)

Port of [*@DominicVanEssen*'s second R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264847/52210).

**Explanation:**

```python
‼     # Apply the next two builtins separately on the current stack:
 w    #  Pop and push a random item from the given (implicit) input-list
  w   #  Same
   ╙  # Pop the top two items on the stack, and leave its maximum
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 bytes

```
⊡⌊×↥⚂⚂⧻.⊏⍏.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=V2VpZ2h0IOKGkCDiiqHijIrDl-KGpeKaguKaguKnuy7iio_ijY8uCldlaWdodCBbNCAyLjIgMi4zIDMgNiA4XQo=)

Built on a similar principle to lots of others others (randomly pick two items and use the max), but tweaked slightly

### Explanation

```
        ⊏⍏. # sort the array
      ⧻.    # get its length
   ↥⚂⚂      # max of two random numbers [0,1)
  ×         # multiply to scale to [0,len)
⊡⌊          # floor and index into array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 44 bytes

```perl
@b=map{($_)x++$,}sort{$a-$b}@F;$_=$b[rand@b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hyTY3saBaQyVes0JbW0Wntji/qKRaJVFXJanWwc1aJd5WJSm6KDEvxSEp9v9/QwUjBWMFEwVTPaN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWJAIA)