# Shuffle a mapping

Tags: code-golf, array, random, permutations

We define a map as a set of key-value pairs.  For this challenge, you need to take each of the values and assign them to a randomly chosen key.

- You must *randomly* shuffle the values, and output the resulting map.  This means that each time we run your program, we have a chance of getting a different output
- Each possible permutation of the values must have a non-zero chance of appearing.
- All of the original keys and original values must appear in the resulting array.  Repeated values must appear the same number of times in the resulting array.

For example, if your map was:

```
[0:10, 1:10, 5:5]
```

*all* of the following must have a chance of appearing:

```
[0:10, 1:10, 5:5]  (original map)
[0:10, 1:5,  5:10]
[0:10, 1:10, 5:5]  (technically the same map, but I swapped the two tens)
[0:10, 1:5,  5:10]
[0:5,  1:10, 5:10]
[0:5,  1:10, 5:10]
```

### Acceptable input/outputs:

- Your languages' native map
- You can input an array of key-value pairs.  You may *not* input 2 arrays, one with keys, the other with values.
- You can use a string representation of any the above
- If you input an array or a map, you can modify the original object instead of returning
- The input type must match the output type
- If you input an array, the order of the keys must be maintained.
- You can assume that the keys are unique, but you cannot assume that values are unique.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so answer as short as possible

Comment: [*Very* closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45302/8478) (The differences are that in mine the keys are simply the indices of the array, that I require a uniform probability over all permutations and that I disallow built-ins.)

Comment: Do the KV pairs have to be in the order `[k, v]` or would `[v, k]` be acceptable?

Comment: They need to be in `[k, v]`

Comment: Can we input a native map and output an array of key-value pairs?

Comment: No, the types need to match.

Comment: The closest equivalent to a map (or array that supports key/value pairs) in **R** is a `list` which only supports string keys, e.g. `list(fish = 1, dog = 2, cat = 3, monkey = 4, harambe = 69)`. Is it requirement to be able to handle integer keys?

Comment: @Billywob that's fine.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Input is a list of key-value pairs.

```
ø       # zip into a list of keys and one of values
 `      # flatten
  .r    # randomize the values
    ø   # zip back again into a list of key-value pairs.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w7hgLnLDuA&input=W1swLDEwXSxbMSwxMF0sWzUsNV1d)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
zt@~T,?zh:Tz
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=enRAflQsP3poOlR6&input=W1swOjEwXTpbMToxMF06WzU6NV1d&args=Wg)

Expects a list of 2-element lists as input.

#### Explanation

```
z              Zip the input to get a list of keys and a list of values
 t@~T,         Take the list of values, and shuffle it ; call that T
      ?zh      Zip the input to get the list of keys
         :Tz   Zip the list of keys with the list of shuffled values
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ṫ€Ẋṭ"
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmq4oKs4bqK4bmtIg&input=&args=W1swLCAxMF0sIFsxLCAxMF0sIFs1LCA1XV0)

### Explanation

```
Ṫ€Ẋṭ"  Input: list of [k, v] pairs
Ṫ€     Pop and return the last element of each k-v pair (modifies each list)
  Ẋ    Shuffle the list of v's
   ṭ"  Append each v back to a k and return
```

Comment: Looks like `TEXt"`

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, 9 bytes

```
{z)mra+z}
```

Input is a list of key-value pairs.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%5B0%2010%5D%20%5B1%2010%5D%20%5B5%205%5D%5D%0A%7Bz)mra%2Bz%7D%0A~p)

#### Explanation

```
z  e# Zip, to separate keys from values.
)  e# Pull off values.
mr e# Shuffle them.
a+ e# Append them to the array again.
z  e# Zip, to restore key-value pairs.
```

Alternative solution, same byte count:

```
{[z~mr]z}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the shortest algorithm in most languages that have Zip :p

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 77 bytes

Uses this option: *If you input an array or a map, you can modify the original object instead of returning*. Input is a dictionary literal like `{0: 10, 1: 10, 5: 5}`.

```python
from random import*
D=input()
k=D.keys()
shuffle(k)
D=dict(zip(k,D.values()))
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/D8xr)

*Inspiration taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997978/2415524).*

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 107 bytes

Uses Python's native dictionary structure.

Thanks to @mbomb007 for saving a byte.

```py
from random import*
def f(d,o={}):
 i=list(d.values());shuffle(i)
 for k in d.keys():o[k]=i.pop()
 return o
```

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/edtMdt)

Comment: Put the import before the function, and use `from random import*`.

Comment: Remove the ``.keys()``. Iterating a dictionary iterates over the keys. Use ``return dict(zip(d, i))`` instead of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 35 bytes

Includes +2 for `-0p`

Give each keys/value separated by space on a STDIN line

```
shuffle.pl
1 5
3 8
9 2
^D
```

`shuffle.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0
@F=/ .*/g;s//splice@F,rand@F,1/eg
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
{#,RandomSample@#2}&@@(#)&
```

Input is a list of key-value pairs. `` is Mathematica's transposition operator, and `RandomSample` can be used to shuffle a list.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>40</s> 34 bytes

```
#(zipmap(keys %)(shuffle(vals %)))
```

Takes the keys and values from m (a map), shuffles the values and zips them up into a map.

Comment: Use the function macro: #(zipmap(keys %)(shuffle(vals %)))

Answer (score 1):

## php, 84 bytes

```
<?= serialise(array_combine(array_keys($a=unserialize($argv[1])),shuffle($a)?$a:0));
```

Takes input as a serialised array, outputs the same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
RandomSample~SubsetMap~All
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PygxLyU/NzgxtyAntS64NKk4tcQ3saDOMSfnf0BRZl5JtLKunXN@aV5JsUNIYlJOanSag7KOoQEQxMaq1QUnJ@bVVXPZ1Bjq2hnqKBjp2hnpKBjr2hnX2HHV/gcA)

Input an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), Mathematica's built-in mapping type.

Since [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) acts on a `List` of values of the subset, keys stay in place while values are shuffled. For some reason, it seems like `SubsetMap` does not consider `;;` a valid `Span` of all elements, so we use `All` instead.

`SubsetMap` was introduced in 2019 (v12.0), postdating this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>73</s> 70 bytes

-3 thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)

```python
lambda d:dict(zip(d,sample([*d.values()],len(d))))
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY33XISc5NSEhVSrFIyk0s0qjILNFJ0ihNzC3JSNaK1UvTKEnNKU4s1NGN1clLzNFI0gYArrSg_V6EoMS8FSGXmFuQXlWhBTYsrKMrMK9FI06hWSsvPV7JSMNBRUEpKLAKyDMGsKiDLqBZoBkKhm78_VKGTYxCU5QsWM0RRCORAbFmwAEIDAA)

Pretty straightforward. I think this is valid Python 3.5 (available at the time of the OP).

Comment: `list(xyz)` could be `[*xyz]`

Comment: Right!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 52 bytes

```
param($a)$a|%{$_[1]}|sort {random}|%{$a[$i++][0],$_}
```

Takes input as an array of tuples, which is significantly shorter than using a hash (which would require `.GetEnumerator()` and whatnot to work).

We loop the input array `|%{...}`, each iteration pulling out the second element `$_[1]`. Those are piped into `Sort-Object` with the `{Get-Random}` as the sorting key. This will assign a random weight from `0` to `[Int32]::MaxValue` to each element for sorting. Those are piped into another loop `|%{...}`, with each iteration outputting a tuple of the corresponding first element of the tuple and the sorted number.

#### Examples

The examples here have an additional `-join','` on the tuple output so it's shown better on the console, as the default output for multi-dimensional arrays is hard to read.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\shuffle-a-mapping.ps1 ((0,10),(1,10),(5,5))
0,10
1,5
5,10

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\shuffle-a-mapping.ps1 ((0,10),(1,10),(5,5))
0,10
1,10
5,5

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\shuffle-a-mapping.ps1 ((1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5))
1,2
2,4
3,3
4,5
5,1
```

This works for non-integer values as well with no modifications.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\shuffle-a-mapping.ps1 (('one','one'),('two','two'),('three','three'),('four','four'))
one,four
two,three
three,two
four,one
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 89 bytes

```
a=>a.map((_,i)=>[i,Math.random()]).sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]).map(([i],j)=>[a[j][0],a[i][1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 28 bytes

```perl6
{%(.keys.pick(*)Z=>.values)}
```

Input is a [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash)
( Technically any value with a [`.keys` method](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/keys) and a [`.values` method](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/values) would work, but the output is a [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) )

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{

  # turn the list of key => value Pairs into a Hash
  %(
      # get the keys from ｢$_｣ ( implicit method call on ｢$_｣ )
      .keys

      # get all of the keys in random order
      .pick(*)

    # zip using ｢&infix:« => »｣ the Pair constructor
    Z[=>]

      # the values from ｢$_｣ ( implicit method call on ｢$_｣ )
      .values
  )
}
```

---

A variant that would work for the other built in Hash like object types is:

```perl6
{.WHAT.(.keys.pick(*)Z=>.values)}
```

`.WHAT` on an object returns the type.

Answer (score 0):

### R,  47 (28) bytes

A bit late to the party but though I'd post a solution in R using builtins.

The closest thing R has to an array with key/value mapping is a `list`. The following function takes a `list` object as input and outputs a list with its values shuffled.

```
function(x)return(setNames(sample(x),names(x)))
```

#### Explained

The builtin `setNames()` can assign names to objects by inputting a `R-vector` of names. Hence, first shuffle the `list` by `sample()` which shuffles the pairs, and then assign the names in the original order using `names()`.

Example:

```
z  <- list(fish = 1, dog = 2, cat = 3, monkey = 4, harambe = 69)

f=function(x)return(setNames(sample(x),names(x)))
f(z)

$fish
[1] 3

$dog
[1] 1

$cat
[1] 2

$monkey
[1] 69

$harambe
[1] 4
```

---

If `x` is assumed to be defined there's no need for function wrapping and the program reduces to 28 bytes.

```
setNames(sample(x),names(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 156 bytes

```
import java.util.*;void c(Map m){List t=new ArrayList(m.values());Collections.shuffle(t);Iterator i=t.iterator();for(Object k:m.keySet())m.put(k,i.next());}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
void c(Map m){
  List t = new ArrayList(m.values());
  Collections.shuffle(t);
  Iterator i = t.iterator();
  for(Object k : m.keySet()){
    m.put(k, i.next());
  }
}
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](http://ideone.com/YWlSLH)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static void c(Map m){List t=new ArrayList(m.values());Collections.shuffle(t);Iterator i=t.iterator();for(Object k:m.keySet())m.put(k,i.next());}
  
  public static void main(String[]a){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      Map m=new HashMap();
      m.put(0, 10);
      m.put(1, 10);
      m.put(5, 5);
      c(m);
      System.out.println(m);
    }
  }
}
```

**Possible output:**

```
{0=5, 1=10, 5=10}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=5, 5=10}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=10, 5=5}
{0=10, 1=5, 5=10}
{0=5, 1=10, 5=10}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 29 bytes

Takes a Hash, returns an array of key-value pairs.

```ruby
:zip%[:keys,:values|:shuffle]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWe62qMgtUo62yUyuLdazKEnNKU4trrIozStPSclJjIWp2Fii4RVcb2NoZGugoGEIoU1s701qo_IIFEBoA)

### [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 37 bytes

Takes a Hash, returns a Hash.

```ruby
(:zip|:to_h)%[:keys,:values|:shuffle]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN1U1rKoyC2qsSvLjMzRVo62yUyuLdazKEnNKU4trrIozStPSclJjIYp3Fii4RVcb2NoZGugoGEIoU1s701qo_IIFEBoA)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 65 bytes

```swift
let f={(k:[(Int,Int)])in[]+zip(k.map(\.0),k.map(\.1).shuffled())}
```

Takes input as an `Array` of tuples, because I'd have to convert a native `Dictionary` into an array of tuples anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a[b=1/Math.random()|0]?f(a,t=a[b][1],a[b][1]=a[0][1],a[0][1]=t):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy7EoIwEEV7vmLLZAiYFDRi9AtsbDMpIiQ@BhIGMjaIvx4XB6u7594z@zQvMzXjY4iFD61NyUkjj0ZdpdidTbyXo/Ft6Al9c31yxLAocdRKaLYlMt/4lzLSvUkXO4GEeakzF0YgjY@IvIb1OICwVQ15jkBhzgBiP@DsiFKcCa4ZKMGEWLNiFdeaooMfFXoaxeLzh2zJmuCn0NmyCzeCNU1f)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda d:{i:d[s]for i,s in zip(d,{*d})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHFqjrTKiW6ODYtv0ghU6dYITNPoSqzQCNFp1orpVaz9n9BUWZeiUaaRrW6gbqVuqGBuo6CuiGcZQpkmarXamr@BwA)

This works because string hashes are randomized in Python.